# js function to get filename from url

Tags: javascript, function

I have a url like http://www.example.com/blah/th.html

I need a javascript function to give me the 'th' value from that.

All my urls have the same format (2 letter filenames, with .html extension).

I want it to be a safe function, so if someone passes in an empty url it doesn't break.

I know how to check for length, but I should be checking for null to right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Comment: For something as specific as you want, you may use RegEx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73341035/7389293

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
var filename = url.split('/').pop()
```

Comment: By far the simplest and best answer.

Comment: what if there are query parameters behind?

Comment: This also doesn't handle URL fragment IDs (i.e. # IDs)

Comment: How about this:

url.split('#').shift().split('?').shift().split('/').pop()

Comment: @hayatbiralem your answer is the correct one : you have to start by cleaning # and  ? and afterwards get split on / or you will get the / in querystring and anchors

Comment: it is almost correct but won't work with `http://domain/THE_PATH?firstParam=BLABLA/BLEBLE".split('/').pop()`

Comment: Not correct at all despite all upvotes! Miss a lot of points.. does not check if url is undefined ... does not split on '.' ... does not remove eventual query string ...

Comment: Even assuming no query string, path, fragment, whatever, doesn't this produce 'th.html' and not 'th', which was what the requester asked for?

Comment: How about this? `new URL(url).pathname.split('/').pop();`

Comment: @Booboo You can add `.split('.')[0]` at the end. So the full line would be `var filename = url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0].split('.')[0];`

Comment: @SangbokLee i guess what you are suggesting is what I implemented here in one of this post's answers.. you may see it here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/53560218/903998

Comment: this solution actually doesn't strip query parameters nor anchors from the url https://i.ibb.co/c3SMNmS/image.png and actually may have some NOT correct results given some url without a path https://i.ibb.co/jJQ4CnC/image.png. It is a very simple solution that works for some cases.

Comment: url.split('/').at(-1);
^-inspired by python slicing.
...and .at(-2); will give you the next-to-last element

Comment: @SangbokLee That approach has to be used like this, unless `url` is 100% guaranteed to been complied the URL format. And if that is guaranteed so, you will likely don't have to use this sort of code, in general.
`(_=>{try{return new URL(__url__).pathname.split('/').pop()}catch{return ''}})()`

Comment: @Victor You may see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795122/6153990

Comment: @SangbokLee That was intended. I originally wrote as `(_=>{try{return new URL(url).pathname.split('/').pop()}catch{return ''}})()` but added underscores for readability. You were wrong because it doesn't pass any parameter. If you really want to do so, this will be correct: `(_=>{try{return new URL(_).pathname.split('/').pop()}catch{return ''}})(url)` But I don't see any reason to do like this in a single line IIFE and even it's longer. You said you wouldn't care but you should do care especially when trying correct others and don't really have to try to dig some fault in others' advice.

Comment: However we don't have to care about this anomore because there are simple and shorter codes which do the similar job: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756650/2047913 - You can chose one in your favor. Allow or not relative URLs, ignore or not trailing slashes, do or don't some validity test. Have a nice 추석 holydays!

Comment: @SangbokLee Oh, come on. What I originally wrote was not at all meaningful. The fact is you were just wrong. Don't you just understand that the above code should not be "corrected" according to your "wrong" suggestion? I said "You were wrong because it doesn't pass any parameter". I can't believe you still have no idea that your attempt to "correction" was wrong. And I doubt how preventing exception could be a "personal" thing. At the first, I said "unless url is 100% guaranteed to been complied the URL format". Do you really think that leaving expected errors uncaught is just personal flavor?

Comment: @SangbokLee See who messed up comments section if you can do a "think". You started it by wrong suggestion in rude command tone. Did you thought I explained those because I just don't want to admit my mistake? Oh, well. Let's assume the placeholder is very important. So what? Nothing is changing. It's still same that what you wrote was just stupid nonsense. My example codelet would work fine without any modification, and what you suggested will break it from working. You really never have to know my original wrote to realize this. So shame on you.

Comment: @Quidn Okay, I've deleted my comments.

Answer (score 107):

Why so difficult?

```
= url.split('#')[0].split('?')[0].split('/').pop();
```

RegEx below would result same as the above's normally, but will return empty string if the URL was significantly malformed.

```
= (url.match(/^\w+:(\/+([^\/#?\s]+)){2,}(#|\?|$)/)||[])[2]||'';
// Returns empty string for relative URLs unlike the original approach

= (url.match(/^\w+:(\/+([^\/#?\s]+)){2,}/)||[])[2]||'';
// Ignores trailing slash (e.g., ".../posts/?a#b" results "posts")
```

---

All three of them would return `file.name` from:

- `my://host/path=&%dir///file.name?q=1/2&3=&#a/?b//?`

The third one would also return `dir.name` from:

- `my://host/path=&%dir///dir.name/?not/these/#/ones//?`

---

**First Edit** (Sep 2023) **:**

- Changed processing order because RFC 3986 explicitly allows fragments to having unencoded slashes. Now it would handles fine even the query("search" in JS) includes unencoded slashes(which obviously had to be encoded).
- This means it might properly handles any form of URLs that most browsers could recognize.
- Using RegEx method was added which includes very basic validity test. Similar concept to the original one but using different approach.

---

Try to test **your** URL by enter below. The third one would ignores trailing slash as described the above code. Please comment if the RegEx ones wouldn't properly handle any valid URL

```html
<style>*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;border:none;}label{font-size:90%}input{display:block;margin:.2em auto 0;padding:.8em 1.2em;width:calc(100% - 5px);background:#f8f8f8;border-radius:1em;}p{margin-top:1.4em;padding-left:.5em;font-size:95%;color:#0008}p::after{content:attr(title);margin-left:.5em;padding:.4em .2em;background:#fe8;border-radius:.5em;font-weight:800;color:#000;}</style>
<label for="input">Enter your URL here:</label>
<input value="my://host/path=&%dir///file.name?q=1/2&3=&#a/?b//?" id="input">
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<script>
((input = document.querySelector('input'), output = document.querySelectorAll('p')) => {
  const getFilename = _=> {
    output[0].title = input.value.split('#')[0].split('?')[0].split('/').pop();
    output[1].title = (input.value.match(/^\w+:(\/+([^\/#?\s]+)){2,}(#|\?|$)/)||[])[2]||'';
    output[2].title = (input.value.match(/^\w+:(\/+([^\/#?\s]+)){2,}/)||[])[2]||'';
  };
  getFilename();
  input.addEventListener('input', getFilename);
  input.select();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Nicely done. Handles presence or absence of `#` and/or `?`.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: @hayatbiralem gave a better answer on another comment : url.split('#').shift().split('?').shift().split('/').pop()

You have to start by splitting on # and ? and afterwards split on / or you will catch the / parts of the anchor and querystring instead of the one from your path (which will typically lead to errors on amazon s3 protected urls )

Comment: What if URL doesn't actually has a filename in it? e.g: `http://www.example.com` this function will return "www.example.com" which is incorrect. It should be either empty string or null.

Comment: Won't work for `"http://www.example.com/filenam.zip?passkey=1/2"`

Comment: @tsh (and Slava too) you are right, do note that other solutions works with those inputs as argument (like this one:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53560218/903998) but not this one. Although this was a good approach for reaching a solution.

Comment: Recently I realized that non-encoded slashes and question marks are explicitly allowed within the fragment due to the RFC 3986. So yes, this won't properly handle some legit URLs and I will rewrite the code later. Thanks for the inform.

Comment: @tsh Use [the version by @hayatbiralem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url/48554885#comment61576914_17143667)

Comment: Or, use the [super sexy version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908174/114558) I just posted!

Comment: @tsh, systho, SlavaFominII, Victor, I fixed all those problems using RegEx while persisted at minimal. Please comment if the new one wouldn't handle any valid URL.

Answer (score 31):

Use the match function.

```
function GetFilename(url)
{
   if (url)
   {
      var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
      if (m && m.length > 1)
      {
         return m[1];
      }
   }
   return "";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have multiple multiple '.'s in the filename

Comment: Does not remove query string

Comment: This will return the name of the file without it's extension.

Answer (score 16):

Similar to the others, but...I've used Tom's simple script - a single line,
then you can use the filename var anywhere:
 http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/02/grab-filename-from-window-location/

```
var filename = location.pathname.substr(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: Length is optional I believe: location.pathname.substr(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1)

Comment: It shows a complete example for googlers like me - small improvement `substr` is deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the existing answers, I would recommend using [`URL() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) (works both in browsers and Node.js) because you can be sure your URL is valid:

```js
const url = 'https://test.com/path/photo123.png?param1=1&param2=2#hash';

let filename = '';
try {
  filename = new URL(url).pathname.split('/').pop();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
console.log(`filename: ${filename}`);
```

Comment: With new built-in Array method we can do `new URL(url).pathname.split('/').at(-1)`. `.pop()` still works tho.

Answer (score 12):

This should work for all cases

```
function getFilenameFromUrl(url) {
  const pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
  const index = pathname.lastIndexOf('/');
  return pathname.substring(index + 1) // if index === -1 then index+1 will be 0
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is the only solution working for all the edge cases I'm aware of. At least in the supported browsers (>89%).

Comment: Not in my browser! **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'**

Comment: Any solution with URL doesn't work for relative URLs

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque you are right this solution doesn't works with "relative URL's" e.g.: `questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url/53560218?noredirect=1#comment111357776_53560218` as using that string the URL object won't be constructed because of an invalid URL as argument. This solution will work with a fully qualified URL or "absolute", i mean, the url must begin with a protocol. In that case you may add an "http://" or ("whatever://") prefix to the relative URL (thus it becomes absolute) and this code will work as a charm.

Comment: Code golf fun: `f=u=>(p=>(i=>-1!==i?p.substring(i+1):p)(p.lastIndexOf('/')))(new URL(u).pathname);`

Comment: You can even omit the `-1 !== index` check and just write `return pathname.substring(index + 1);` since -1 + 1 will return 0.

Comment: @Robbendebiene nice move!! updating snippet!

Answer (score 8):

A regex solution which accounts for URL query and hash identifier:

```
function fileNameFromUrl(url) {
   var matches = url.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)[^\/]*$/);
   if (matches.length > 1) {
     return matches[1];
   }
   return null;
}
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zoxyoymn/10/).

Comment: This is the best answer when using regex.

Comment: What if URL doesn't actually has a filename in it? e.g: `http://www.example.com` this function will return "www.example.com" which is incorrect. It should be either empty string or null.

Answer (score 6):

Because cases tend to fail with custom code, I looked up to the JavaScript `URL` class. Alas, it chokes on relative URLs! Also, it doesn't have a property to get the file name. *Not epic.*

There *has* to be a good library out there which solves this common problem. [Behold URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/tree/master). All you need is a simple statement like the following:

```
let file = new URI(url).filename()
```

Then we can create a simple function that does null checks and removes the file extension:

```
function fileName(url) {
   if (url === null || typeof url === 'undefined')
      return ''
   let file = new URI(url).filename() // File name with file extension
   return file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) // Remove the extension
}
```

Here's a snippet with test cases to play around with. All cases pass except drive paths.

```js
test('Dots in file name without URL', 'dotted.file.name.png', 'dotted.file.name')
test('Dots in file name with URL', 'http://example.com/file.name.txt', 'file.name')
test('Lengthy URL with parameters', '/my/folder/filename.html#dssddsdsd?toto=33&dududu=podpodpo', 'filename')
test('URL with hash', '/my/folder/filename.html#dssddsdsd', 'filename')
test('URL with query strings', '/my/folder/filename.html?toto=33&dududu=podpodp', 'filename')
test('Hash after query string', 'http://www.myblog.com/filename.php?year=2019#06', 'filename')
 test('Query parameter with file path character', 'http://www.example.com/filename.zip?passkey=1/2', 'filename')
test('Query parameter with file path character and hash', 'http://www.example.com/filename.html?lang=en&user=Aan9u/o8ai#top', 'filename')
test('Asian characters', 'http://example.com/文件名.html', '文件名')
test('URL without file name', 'http://www.example.com', '')
test('Null', null, '')
test('Undefined', undefined, '')
test('Empty string', '', '')
test('Drive path name', 'C:/fakepath/filename.csv', 'filename')

function fileName(url) {
   if (url === null || typeof url === 'undefined')
      return ''
   let file = new URI(url).filename() // File name with file extension
   return file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) // Remove the extension
}

function test(description, input, expected) {
   let result = fileName(input)
   let pass = 'FAIL'
   if (result === expected)
      pass = 'PASS'
   console.log(pass + ': ' + description + ': ' + input)
   console.log('  =>  "' + fileName(input) + '"')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/medialize/URI.js@master/src/URI.js"></script>
```

**Results**

```
PASS: Dots in file name without URL: dotted.file.name.png
  =>  "dotted.file.name"
PASS: Dots in file name with URL: http://example.com/file.name.txt
  =>  "file.name"
PASS: Lengthy URL with parameters: /my/folder/filename.html#dssddsdsd?toto=33&dududu=podpodpo
  =>  "filename"
PASS: URL with hash: /my/folder/filename.html#dssddsdsd
  =>  "filename"
PASS: URL with query strings: /my/folder/filename.html?toto=33&dududu=podpodp
  =>  "filename"
PASS: Hash after query string: http://www.myblog.com/filename.php?year=2019#06
  =>  "filename"
PASS: Query parameter with file path character: http://www.example.com/filename.zip?passkey=1/2
  =>  "filename"
PASS: Query parameter with file path character and hash: http://www.example.com/filename.html?lang=en&user=Aan9u/o8ai#top
  =>  "filename"
PASS: Asian characters: http://example.com/文件名.html
  =>  "文件名"
PASS: URL without file name: http://www.example.com
  =>  ""
PASS: Null: null
  =>  ""
PASS: Undefined: undefined
  =>  ""
PASS: Empty string: 
  =>  ""
FAIL: Drive path name: C:/fakepath/filename.csv
  =>  ""
```

This solution is for you if you're too lazy to write custom code and don't mind using a library to do work for you. It isn't for you if you want to code golf the solution.

Answer (score 5):

those will not work for lenghty url like
**"/my/folder/questions.html#dssddsdsd?toto=33&dududu=podpodpo"**

here I expect to get "questions.html".
So a possible (slow) solution is as below

```
fname=function(url) 
{ return url?url.split('/').pop().split('#').shift().split('?').shift():null }
```

then you can test that in any case you get only the filename.

```
fname("/my/folder/questions.html#dssddsdsd?toto=33&dududu=podpodpo")
-->"questions.html"
fname("/my/folder/questions.html#dssddsdsd")
-->"questions.html"
fname("/my/folder/questions.html?toto=33&dududu=podpodpo")
"-->questions.html"

(and it works for null)
```

(I would love to see a faster or smarter solution)

Comment: Why do you expect to get "questions.html" when it is asked for get the name "questions" only?

Comment: Wrong. file extension is part of the name right? and it is asked filename right?

Comment: See the second line in question: I need a javascript function to give me the 'th' value from that.

Comment: Ok, I missed it ;-)
Then it is a onliner ie .split('.').pop()

Answer (score 5):

This answer only works in browser environment. Not suitable for node.

```js
function getFilename(url) {
  const filename = decodeURIComponent(new URL(url).pathname.split('/').pop());
  if (!filename) return 'index.html'; // some default filename
  return filename;
}

function filenameWithoutExtension(filename) {
  return filename.replace(/^(.+?)(?:\.[^.]*)?$/, '$1');
}
```

Here are two functions:

- first one get filename from url
- second one get filename without extension from a full filename

For parsing URL, new an `URL` object should be the best choice. Also notice that URL do not always contain a filename.

**Notice:** This function try to resolve filename from an URL. But it do NOT guarantee that the filename is valid and suitable for use:

- Some OS disallow certain character in filename (e.g. `:` in windows, `\0` in most OS, ...);
- Some filename may reserved by OS (e.g. `CON` in windows);
- Some filename may make user unhappy to handle it (e.g. a file named "--help" in Linux)

---

Test it out:

```js
function getFilename(url) {
  const filename = decodeURIComponent(new URL(url).pathname.split('/').pop());
  if (!filename) return 'index.html'; // some default filename
  return filename;
}

function test(url) {
  console.log('Filename: %o\nUrl: %o', getFilename(url), url);
}

test('http://www.example.com');
test('http://www.example.com/');
test('http://www.example.com/name.txt');
test('http://www.example.com/path/name.txt');
test('http://www.example.com/path/name.txt/realname.txt');
test('http://www.example.com/page.html#!/home');
test('http://www.example.com/page.html?lang=en&user=Aan9u/o8ai#top');
test('http://www.example.com/%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E5%90%8D.txt')
```

Comment: Why make it so complicated? It gets unsafe.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho What do you mean by _unsafe_? Anything here is _unsafe_?

Comment: Simplicity = Safe. See my solution. Complexity = Unsafe.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho But an answer should first be correct, then simple. And I can't see how simple = safe holds.

Comment: As you note some OS may have issues `URL()` and some browsers do not support it? Where is `filenameWithoutExtension()` used?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho `URL` is browser specified, if you are using node.js, you may want some package which provide similar functions to it. Most recent browsers should support `URL`, but this may missing if you are working on old ones like IE. A filename contains special characters may not be valid on some OS, that's nothing to do with how to parse it (e.g. `http://www.example.com/a|b.txt` would be perfect valid URL. And `a|b.txt` would also be valid, but confusing, filename on Linux. But you cannot / should not name a file like this on Windows.

Comment: Sounds unsafe to me. How can I check `"https://www.example.com/"` or `"https://www.example.com"` give empty file name with your solution?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho If so, you only need the first line, `decodeURIComponent(new URL('http://www.example.com').pathname.split('/').pop());` will give you empty string as you expected.

Comment: I remember your advise: *an answer should first be correct, then simple* - Very good! We are right on different things, but sure you are right.. often safety may require more code.. fore example check on null and fixes of all kinds to not break. Devil is in the details.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. +1 for using URL and +99 for decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `substring` function combined with `lastIndexOf`. This will allow for filenames with periods in them e.g. given `http://example.com/file.name.txt` this gives `file.name` unlike the accepted answer that would give `file`.

```
function GetFilename(url)
{
    if (url)
    {
        return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should handle anything you throw at it (absolute URLs, relative URLs, complex AWS URLs, etc). It includes an optional default or uses a psuedorandom string if neither a filename nor a default were present.

```
function parseUrlFilename(url, defaultFilename = null) {
    let filename = new URL(url, "https://example.com").href.split("#").shift().split("?").shift().split("/").pop(); //No need to change "https://example.com"; it's only present to allow for processing relative URLs.
    if(!filename) {
        if(defaultFilename) {
            filename = defaultFilename;
        //No default filename provided; use a pseudorandom string.
        } else {
            filename = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
        }
    }
    
    return filename;
}
```

Props to @hayatbiralem for [nailing the order of the `split()`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/511761#comment61576914_17143667).

Comment: probably one of the best answers i've seen on SO... reason saying that is thorough and intuitive for testing

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery with the [URL plugin](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/):

```
var file = jQuery.url.attr("file");
var fileNoExt = file.replace(/\.(html|htm)$/, "");
// file == "th.html", fileNoExt = "th"
```

Answer (score 1):

For node and browsers, based on @pauls answer but solving issues with hash and more defensive:

```
export function getFileNameFromUrl(url) {
  const hashIndex = url.indexOf('#')
  url = hashIndex !== -1 ? url.substring(0, hashIndex) : url
  return (url.split('/').pop() || '').replace(/[\?].*$/g, '')
}
```

Few cases:

```
describe('getFileNameFromUrl', () => {

  it('absolute, hash and no extension', () => {
    expect(getFileNameFromUrl(
      'https://foo.bar/qs/bar/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url#comment95124061_53560218'))
    .toBe('js-function-to-get-filename-from-url')
  })

  it('relative, extension and parameters', () => {
    expect(getFileNameFromUrl('../foo.png?ar=8')).toBe('foo.png')
  })

  it('file name with multiple dots, hash with slash', () => {
    expect(getFileNameFromUrl('questions/511761/js-function.min.js?bar=9.9&y=1#/src/jjj?=9.9')).toBe('js-function.min.js')
  })
})
```

Comment: It is not Javascript

Comment: `http://www.example.com/page.html?lang=en&user=Aan9u/o8ai#top`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what @user2492653 suggested, if all you want is the name of the file like Firefox gives you, then you the split() method, which breaks the string into an array of components, then all you need to do it grab the last index.

```
var temp = url.split("//");
if(temp.length > 1)
 return temp[temp.length-1] //length-1 since array indexes start at 0
```

This would basically break C:/fakepath/test.csv into {"C:", "fakepath", "test.csv"}

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents

the LastIndexOf("/") method in itself falls down if the querystrings contain "/"

We all know they "should" be encoded as `%2F` but it would only take one un-escaped value to cause problems.

This version correctly handles /'s in the querystrings and has no reliance on .'s in the url

```
function getPageName() {
    //#### Grab the url
    var FullUrl = window.location.href;

    //#### Remove QueryStrings
    var UrlSegments = FullUrl.split("?")
    FullUrl = UrlSegments[0];

    //#### Extract the filename
    return FullUrl.substr(FullUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```

Comment: True, but the importance of query solutions is questionable because it is not mentioned in the question. It is a choise between using '/' in query if any query at all or having shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length)
```

Comment: Works if you change url.length. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFileNameWithoutExtension(url) {
  if (typeof url !== 'string') throw new Error('url must be a string');
  // Remove the QueryString
  return url.replace(/\?.*$/, '')
  // Extract the filename
  .split('/').pop()
  // Remove the extension
  .replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');
}
```

This will return `news` from this URL http://www.myblog.com/news.php?year=2019#06.

Comment: Doesn't split on '.' to remove the extension as asked for

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho you are right, it seems I did not read the question well, I corrected my answer. My code is less performant than the accepted answer, however it works with filenames like "news.inc.php" and it is easier to read.

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct at all: *Miss a lot of points.. does not check if url is undefined ... does not split on '.' ... does not remove eventual query string ...*. It is my comment there

Answer (score 0):

```
url? url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.lastIndexOf('.')):''
```

- Safety is as asked for. when url is `null` or `undefined` the result is **`''`**.
- Removes all of the path with ':', dots and any symbol including the last '/'.
- This gives the true answer **'th'** as asked and not **'th.index'**. That is **very important** of course to have it work at all.
- It allows filename to have several periods!
- Not asked, but you can also have a query string without '/' and '.'

*It is a corrected answer from Abhishek Sharma so I gave him an upvote. So genious and minimal one-liner - I saw it there :)*

Comment: See my last point: *Not asked, but you can also have a query string without '/' and '.'* so that url has '/' in the query.

Comment: Between last '/' and last '.' is an empty name and I checked that gave it correctly ignoring the `.vimrc` extension.

Comment: It gives `%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E5%90%8D`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I pasted the symbols into `http://example.com/文件名.html` and the `alert()` say `文件名`

Answer (score 0):

#### ES6 syntax based on TypeScript

Actually, the marked answer is true but if the second `if` doesn't satisfy the function returns `undefined`, I prefer to write it like below:

```js
const getFileNameFromUrl = (url: string): string => {
  if (url) {
    const tmp = url.split('/');
    const tmpLength = tmp.length;

    return tmpLength ? tmp[tmpLength - 1] : '';
  }

  return '';
};
```

For my problem, I need to have the file extension.

Comment: If someone doesn't need the file extension then can use `split('.')` on returned string and join all elements without last entry of array.

Comment: @ArkadiuszWieczorek, Exactly you right, thanks for your hint. 

Answer (score 0):

##### Simple Function (Using RegEx Pattern)

```js
function pathInfo(s) {
    s=s.match(/(.*?\/)?(([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+?)?)(?:[?#].*)?$/);
    return {path:s[1],file:s[2],name:s[3],ext:s[4]};
}

var sample='/folder/another/file.min.js?query=1';
var result=pathInfo(sample);
console.log(result);
/*
{
  "path": "/folder/another/",
  "file": "file.min.js",
  "name": "file.min",
  "ext": ".js"
}
*/
console.log(result.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using RegEx

Let´s say you have this url:

```html
http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/blog/posts/1660345251.html
```

Using the following line of code:

```js
var filename = location.pathname.replace(/[\D]/g, "");
```

Will return:

```html
1660345251
```

- Notice that this number is [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which returns your local time no matter where you are in the World (this should give you really unique post names for this blog example).
- `.replace(/[\D]/g, "")`, replaces any non-digit character with an empty string. `/[\D]/g` says non-digit, and `""` says empty string. More about it: [here for numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers) and [here for letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136947/javascript-regex-to-return-letters-only).
- More about RegEx, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex). There are lots of RegEx tools out there that can help you out to get better results in the returning value for `filename`.

### Extra code: Unix Time to Local Time

```js
var humanDate = new Date(0);
var timestamp = entries[index].timestamp;
humanDate.setUTCSeconds(timestamp);
```

`humanDate` is for my local time:

```html
Fri Aug 12 2022 20:00:51 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)
```

Credits for this code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016205/7389293).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFilenameFromUrlString(url) {
 const response = {
   data: {
     filename: ""
   },
   error: ""
 };
 try {
   response.data.filename = new URL(url).pathname.split("/").pop();
 } catch (e) {
   response.error = e.toString();
 }
 return response;
}
```

For tests check this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/get-filename-from-url-string-wqthx1

Answer (score 0):

if any lazy person just wants the file name without extension,here it is

```
const url='https://test.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/d.pdf';
const filename = url.split('/').pop().split('.')[0] //187392504
```

Answer (score -1):

from [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```