# Regex using javascript to return just numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string like "something12" or "something102", how would I use a regex in javascript to return just the number parts?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Regular expressions:

```js
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

'something102asdfkj1948948'.match( numberPattern )
```

This would return an Array with two elements inside, '102' and '1948948'. Operate as you wish. If it doesn't match any it will return null.

To concatenate them:

```js
'something102asdfkj1948948'.match( numberPattern ).join('')
```

Assuming you're not dealing with complex decimals, this should suffice I suppose.

Comment: err. hate to be nit-picky, but this returns an array, not an object (at least in chrome).

Comment: All arrays are objects though, no?

Comment: how about `parseInt(string);`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - did you try it?

Comment: paseInt or what's above. i tried both, both output the same thing. Update nvm, i was using it for removing px from '34px'. and that's where parseint only works, where all numbers are first letters.

Comment: @meder Sort of. `Arrays` inherit from `Objects`. For starters, `Array` item order is guaranteed, `Object` order is not. Also, `Arrays` have an additional Object in their prototype chain, `Array.prototype`, which contains methods like `.join()`. Something like the following would raise an error on `.join` and return `.length` as undefined: `var pattern = /\d+/g;
var string = 'something102asdfkj1948948';
var result = string.match( pattern );
result.join('');
result.length;`

Comment: @Onza you are missing the backslash before the `d`, so `.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, @meder: You two should combine forces:

`parseInt('987d98sf79s7f9s8f9sf'.match(/\d+/gi).join(''))`

Comment: To check for negatives (For example `blah blah -42 hello` should return `-42`), 
 use `numberPattern = /(\d+|-)/g;` then use `join`

Comment: why we are using +

Answer (score 233):

You could also strip all the non-digit characters (`\D` or `[^0-9]`):

```js
let word_With_Numbers = 'abc123c def4567hij89'
let numbers = word_With_Numbers.replace(/\D/g, '');

console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Well, except that the OP wants "just the number parts," not the string.

Comment: @ScottFraley note that this code uses the `replace` method, not the `match` method ;)

Comment: doesn't work with decimals. It should preserve the decimal too

Answer (score 51):

For number with decimal fraction and minus sign, I use this snippet:

```js
const NUMERIC_REGEXP = /[-]{0,1}[\d]*[,]?[\d]*[.]{0,1}[\d]+/g;

const numbers = '2.2px -6,543.1px 4px -7.6px obj.key'.match(NUMERIC_REGEXP)

console.log(numbers); // ["2.2", "3.1", "4", "-7.6"]
```

**Update: - 7/9/2018**

Found a tool which allows you to edit regular expression visually: **[JavaScript Regular Expression Parser & Visualizer](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24)**.

**Update:**

Here's another one with which you can even debugger regexp: **[Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)**.

**Update:**

Another one: **[RegExr](https://regexr.com/)**.

**Update:**

**[Regexper](https://regexper.com/)** and **[Regex Pal](https://www.regexpal.com/)**.

Comment: Perfect, only solution that works with decimals and negative nums

Comment: doesn't work with comma as digit separator

Answer (score 19):

If you want only digits:

```
var value = '675-805-714';
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
value = value.match( numberPattern ).join([]);
alert(value);
//Show: 675805714
```

Now you get the digits joined

Answer (score 11):

I guess you want to get number(s) from the string. In which case, you can use the following:

```
// Returns an array of numbers located in the string
function get_numbers(input) {
    return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}

var first_test = get_numbers('something102');
var second_test = get_numbers('something102or12');
var third_test = get_numbers('no numbers here!');

alert(first_test); // [102]
alert(second_test); // [102,12]
alert(third_test); // null
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, `get_numbers/1` returns an array of string, not number. For your example, it would return:

* `["102"]`
* `["102", "12"]`
* null

Answer (score 7):

IMO the  [#3 answer at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264780/4941356) by Chen Dachao is the right way to go if you want to capture any kind of number, but the regular expression can be shortened from:

```
/[-]{0,1}[\d]*[\.]{0,1}[\d]+/g
```

to:

```
/-?\d*\.?\d+/g
```

For example, this code:

```
"lin-grad.ient(217deg,rgba(255, 0, 0, -0.8), rgba(-255,0,0,0) 70.71%)".match(/-?\d*\.?\d+/g)
```

generates this array:

```
["217","255","0","0","-0.8","-255","0","0","0","70.71"]
```

I've butchered an MDN linear gradient example so that it fully tests the regexp and doesn't need to scroll here. I think I've included all the possibilities in terms of negative numbers, decimals, unit suffixes like deg and %, inconsistent comma and space usage, and the extra dot/period and hyphen/dash characters within the text "lin-grad.ient". Please let me know if I'm missing something. The only thing I can see that it does not handle is a badly formed decimal number like "0..8".

If you really want an array of numbers, you can convert the entire array in the same line of code:

```
array = whatever.match(/-?\d*\.?\d+/g).map(Number);
```

My particular code, which is parsing CSS functions, doesn't need to worry about the non-numeric use of the dot/period character, so the regular expression can be even simpler:

```
/-?[\d\.]+/g
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = input.match(/\d+/g).join([])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using split and regex :

```
    var str = "fooBar0123".split(/(\d+)/);
    console.log(str[0]); // fooBar
    console.log(str[1]); // 0123
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers given don't actually match your question, which implied a *trailing* number. Also, remember that you're getting a string back; if you actually **need** a number, cast the result:

```
item=item.replace('^.*\D(\d*)$', '$1');
if (!/^\d+$/.test(item)) throw 'parse error: number not found';
item=Number(item);
```

If you're dealing with numeric item ids on a web page, your code could also usefully accept an `Element`, extracting the number from its `id` (or its first parent with an `id`); if you've an `Event` handy, you can likely get the `Element` from that, too.

Comment: While this is a nifty answer I do not think that the other answers "don't actually match [the] question". In fact the other answers are more versatile. They will work with trailing numbers as well as numbers in the middle. It is a bit presumptuous to assume the OP wanted it to ONLY work with trailing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Syntle's answer, if you have only non numeric characters you'll get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null`.

This will prevent errors if no matches are found and return an empty string:

`('something'.match( /\d+/g )||[]).join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to convert the string to valid plain or decimal numbers using Regex:

```
//something123.777.321something to 123.777321
const str = 'something123.777.321something';
let initialValue = str.replace(/[^0-9.]+/, '');
//initialValue = '123.777.321';

//characterCount just count the characters in a given string
if (characterCount(intitialValue, '.') > 1) {
 const splitedValue = intitialValue.split('.');
 //splittedValue = ['123','777','321'];
 intitialValue = splitedValue.shift() + '.' + splitedValue.join('');
 //result i.e. initialValue = '123.777321'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const NUMERIC_REGEXP = /[-]{0,1}[\d]*[.]{0,1}[\d]+/g;

const numbers = '2.2px 3.1px 4px -7.6px obj.key'.match(NUMERIC_REGEXP)

console.log(numbers); // ["2.2", "3.1", "4", "-7.6"]
```

[Chen Dachao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264780/1623425)
answer is perfect. Same, but a little shorter

```
/-?\d*[.]?\d+/g
```

Comment: you could just comment your opinion to prevent repetition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dot/comma separated numbers also, then:

```
\d*\.?\d*
```

or

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

You can use https://regex101.com/ to test your regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that other solutions have, but with a little validation

```
// value = '675-805-714'
const validateNumberInput = (value) => { 
    let numberPattern = /\d+/g 
    let numbers = value.match(numberPattern)

    if (numbers === null) {
        return 0
    }  

    return parseInt(numbers.join([]))
}
// 675805714
```

Answer (score 0):

### One liner

I you do not care about decimal numbers and only need the digits, I think this one liner is rather elegant:

```js
/**
 * @param {String} str
 * @returns {String} - All digits from the given `str`
 */
const getDigitsInString = (str) => str.replace(/[^\d]*/g, '');

console.log([
  '?,!_:/42\`"^',
  'A 0 B 1 C 2 D 3 E',
  ' 4 twenty 20 ',
  '1413/12/11',
  '16:20:42:01'
].map((str) => getDigitsInString(str)));
```

### Simple explanation:

- `\d` matches any digit from 0 to 9
- `[^n]` matches anything that is not `n`
- `*` matches 0 times or more the predecessor
  *( It is an attempt to match a whole block of non-digits all at once )*
- `g` at the end, indicates that the regex is `global` to the entire string and that we will not stop at the first occurrence but match every occurrence within it

Together those rules match anything but digits, which we replace by an empty strings. Thus, resulting in a string containing digits only.