# Regex - how to parse multiple numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I parse multiple numbers via regex in javascript?

Assume the input:

```
foooo 123 bar<br>456 x 789 baz<br>mumumu 321 yarrr
```

I want to fetch the 123 , 456,789,321 as separate tokens.

New to both javascript and regex so I feel sort of stuck trying to fetch multiple values

Comment: Let the downvote hailstorm begin :)

Comment: You should really go through some tutorials before posting such a question =/

Comment: I guess a simple `.match(/\d+/g)` should do...

Comment: Or learn to use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) or Google

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex using javascript to return just numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var str = "foooo 123 bar<br>456 x 789 baz<br>mumumu 321 yarrr",
    numbers = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
console.log(numbers);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LvAan/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: I'd suggest to not feed the OP nor code requesters

Comment: Because that's what we're here for, to *not* help people with their code? I accept that some research could have been undertaken, or at least *demonstrated* in the question; but I'd rather show an answer (or, in some cases, how to *come* to an answer) and link to some reference material that might help the OP out in future instead of criticising their temerity to ask us a question.

Comment: I beg to differ with your provision of code. Although, I agree that providing some references is OK but it should had been done in a comment. Either way, the correct thing to do which you didn't do, as well as the OP didn't even do, was to search and mark as duplicate this question

Comment: As to your latter point, I have.