# How to strip text values from an array result so have only numeric value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How do I extract a value from a database item in an array that contains both text and the value I want.

For example the first item in array:

```
resultArray[i].selector_sliderdata_attributes
```

is the value:  data-time-build='100'

The second item has the value:  data-time-build='450'
and so on.

I want to be able to extract the 100 and 450 in my js function and use it to compare values in my isotope slider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can use regex:

```
var NumOnly = YourString.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this one first because it was so simple to insert into my code and it worked perfectly the first time.  Awesome.  So my solution was: var NumOnly = resultArray[i].selector_sliderdata_attributes.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map your array to a number map like so:

```
array.map(function(value, index){
    return +value.match(/\d+/);
});
```

* the `+` turns the result into a number

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to use this solution so I tried the one below first.  It worked, but I would be curious as to how this would be implemented.

Comment: For an array of strings it will return an array of numbers within the strings