# Javascript: use regex to find digits in the matching string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I understand how to retrieve digits from a string after reading [Regex using javascript to return just numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers)

I am wondering if I can validate my input at the same time. While implementing an LMS, I am looking for input strings matching "`com.interactions.*n*.objectives.*m*.id`", where *n* & *m* are integers.

In one regex function, can I retrieve the digits n & m ONLY IF my input string matches the pattern above? Or do I need to first validate the input string, and then pull the digits out afterwards?

Comment: Use: `var m = str.match(/^com\.interactions\.(\d+)\.objectives\.(\d+)\.id$/);` and use `m[1]` and `m[2]` for your 2 values.

Comment: To my SCORM audience cringing - the pattern really starts with 'cmi', not 'com', but changing it now would compromise the answers. My head was in Androidland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String#match` with **capturing groups**:

```
var m = str.match(/^cmi\.interactions\.(\d+)\.objectives\.(\d+)\.id$/i);
```

and use `m[1]` and `m[2]` for the 2 values (integers) you want to capture.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indeed do both. I've made you this document so you can try it out: https://tonicdev.com/tonic/regex-validation

I recommend using the ^ and $ at the beginning and end of the regex, if not aaacom.interactions.55.objects.66.id would match for example (since the match can appear *anywhere* in the string otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for matching the valid string and getting the digits via capture groups:

```
com\.interactions\.(\d+)\.objectives\.(\d+)\.id
```

https://regex101.com/r/jW9sP6/1