# split string in numeric values and non nummeric numbers regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this css string

```
var cssString = 'scale(0.95,0.95) rotate(45deg) translate(10px,11px)';
```

I want to use regex to return an array looking like this:

```
var array = ['scale(','0.95',',','0.95',') rotate(','45','deg) translate(','10','px,','11','px)'];
```

my last attempt:

```
var array = cssString.match(/([ a-zA-Z])*(\d*[.]?\d*)*/g);
```

I'm struggeling to have the first group match the parantheses aswell. How do I make this happen?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers) might help

Comment: @GustvandeWal your suggestion ignores deicmal numbers

Answer (score 0):

This regex will separately select both text (with special characters `()`) and numbers (with dots `.`) and the commas:

```
([A-Za-z()])+|(,)+|([.\d])+
```

Comment: It doesn't return this tho: `) rotate(` If you would look at my array?

Comment: My bad. Try this: `([A-Za-z\s()])+|(,)+|([.\d])+`

Comment: I'm sorry, your current example did indeed work before my last edit. I made a mistake in that return value. The idea is that I can iterate over it with a for loop and use an even/odd principle to retrieve numbers or other. Can you take a look at it again?

Comment: Sure. Use this: `([\sA-Za-z(),])+|(,)+|([.\d])+`

Comment: I have a few questions regarding regex. Can abduct you to a [chat]?

Comment: I'm unable to use [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) it requires proxy authentication. For now, i'm new here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100764/discussion-between-puddingboy-and-filipe-costa-meneses).

Comment: I was just wondering, considering your placement of the `,` in the first group. Does this not mean the second group could be removed? The new regex would look like this I suppose `([\sA-Za-z(),])+|([.\d])+`

Comment: That will do it, but it also will merge `,` to any `\sa-zA-Z()`. So it wont produce: `'scale(0.95,0.95)'` => `['scale(','0.95',',','0.95',')']`. You can check it right [here](http://regexr.com/3cjml)

Comment: What do you mean? The idea was to only have 2 groups, nums(float included) and non-nums. `/([\sA-Za-z(),])+|([.\d])+/g` would do just fine to do this or? I don't think any `,` exists outside of `(...)` and inside, they are always followed by a number. Where do you suspect issues?