# Spliting numbers out of a string contain characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I want to split the numbers out of a string and put them in an array using Regex.

For example, I have a string 
`23a43b3843c9293k234nm5g%>`and using regex I need to get `[23,43,3843,9293,234,5]`
in an array

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Another one [Regex using javascript to return just numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

*The `match()` method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression*

**Edit:** As suggested by Tushar, Use `Array.prototype.map` and argument as `Number` to cast it as Number.

Try this:

```js
var exp = /[0-9]+/g;
var input = "23a43b3843c9293k234nm5g%>";
var op = input.match(exp).map(Number);
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "23a43b3843c9293k234nm5g%>";
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
alert(text.match(regex));
```

You get a match object with all of your numbers.

The script above correctly alerts 23,43,3843,9293,234,5.

see Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5WJ9v/307/