# is there a way to extract the number from .innerText

Tags: javascript, numbers, innertext

Lets say I've created some code where the user can keep adding numbers to a `<ul>` and next to each `<li>` is a delete button which can be used to remove said item off the list. The problem is for it to work each item on the list does not only contain a number it also contains some text. Lets just say:

```
<li>Bag of potatoes - 25kg</li>
```

is there any way that I can use .innerText on this list item, to then just extract the number 25 (or whatever number happens to be there) so that I can subtract it from the total.

I have tried the following:

```
const itemText = item.parentElement.innerText;
const itemWeight = itemText.match(/\d/g) || [];
```

However in this example it returns 2,5 rather than 25. Is there a simple way I can convert the result 2,5 to 25, or is it possible to do this in a more efficient manner?

Thanks

Comment: `\d` only matches a single digit. Use `.match(/\d+/g)` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex using javascript to return just numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

as @Zsolt mentions in the comments you should add \d+ where the + means matches the previous match (the \d one) one and unlimited time. so you will get all the numbers in the text.

```
const itemWeight = itemText.match(/\d+/g) || [];
```

I really encourage you to play around with this website [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
it is designed to help you understand the regular expression and test them so on...

I hope that solves your problem. Thanks