# Javascript toUTCString hours off

Tags: javascript, utc

I am getting a JSON string back from a webservice. I have tested this same thing on the W3C Schools site too for our local machine.
The time I am getting back for both the service and the W3C site from the UTC string via Javascript is 2 hours ahead.  Any ideas how to fix this or do I need to adjust for daylight savings, or something else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the code you are using at this point

Comment: Ugh. Dates and javascript. Do all your date work on the server if you can, I say.

Answer (score 0):

If you are living in a GMT-2 zone, you should get UTC time 2 hours ahead. If that's the case and you want to get local date, here is your answer.

[Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript)