# javascript setUTCMilliseconds is wrong? Otherwise, I'm wrong

Tags: javascript, date, utc, milliseconds

Am I implementing setUTCMilliseconds incorrectly? I get the incorrect date for any value I put in. Here is just one example of a wrong value. All my test data resolves to May 24 (the future from now) in JS, but in C# or using quick online conversion tools, my UTS MS are correct.

any thoughts?

```
function parseDate(epoch) {   
    var d = new Date();

    //tried this too, but it shows me the actual epoch 1970 date instead
    //var d = new Date(0);

    //EDIT: this should be seconds in combination with Date(0)
    d.setUTCMilliseconds(parseInt(epoch)); 

    return d.toString();
}

 // 1336423503 -> Should be Mon May 07 2012 13:45:03 GMT-7

 // javascript says
 Thu May 24 2012 05:03:21 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Comment: The value you are passing isn't an epoch, it's a time **since** the epoch.

Comment: yeah, i understand what the number means. i'm using it here like epochtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a similar question:

```
var utcMilliseconds = 1234567890000;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCMilliseconds(utcMilliseconds);
```

See [Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript).

Comment: yeah i tried that, and it just showed me the epoch date in 1970.

Comment: ah, okay, do need 0, but didn't notice its seconds, not ms.

Comment: Since the time is being passed in seconds, you can do: `d.setUTCSeconds(seconds, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

To convert a UTC time in seconds to a local date object:

```
function makeUTC(secs) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(1970,0,1,0,0, secs, 0));
}
```

Note that the epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00.0Z

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor with milliseconds as a number:

```
> new Date(1336423503 * 1000)
2012-05-07T20:45:03.000
```

There is no need to create a Date object and setUTCMilliseconds afterwards.