# document.lastModified in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a webpage that displays the last time it was updated using `document.write(document.lastModified)`. I get two different results when I view the page in Chrome and in Firefox. Firefox displays the time correctly - in my local time. Chrome displays it in UTC.

1. How do I get Chrome to display the datetime in either (a) local time of whoever is vieweing the page or (b) in PDT/PST (simpler)
2. Is there a solution that will display local time on both Chrome and Firefox (and others)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked how it is accomplished on Google Chrome but frankly I haven't been able to find anything useful except these two methods you can use.

I believe this method can help you:

```
function ToLocalDate (inDate) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(inDate.valueOf() - 60000 * inDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    return date;
}
```

Just check the browser type and call this method accordingly after.

Or you can also use the following method:

```
var utc_string = '2011-09-05 20:05:15';
var local_string = (function(dtstr) {
    var t0 = new Date(dtstr);
    var t1 = Date.parse(t0.toUTCString().replace('GMT', ''));
    var t2 = (2 * t0) - t1;
    return new Date(t2).toString();
})(utc_string);
```

These answers are taken from this address: [Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript)