# Parsing the C# datetime to javascript datetime

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime

I know that my question is similar to others but I didn't found any solution to my problem.

I have a C# DateTime property

```
 public DateTime MyDate { get;set;}
```

When I use an ajax to get some information, I wrote in javascript something like:

```
$.each(object, function(k,v){
  alert(object.MyDate);
});
```

It returns something like:

```
/Date(1362478277517)/
```

It is possible to convert that datetime to javascript date ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like seconds from epoch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`new Date(object.MyDate);` should work.

EDIT:
`var date = new Date(parseInt(object.MyDate.substr(6)));`

I've also seen this method:

```
var milli = "/Date(1245398693390)/".replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
var d = new Date(parseInt(milli));
```

Comment: Is it just me, or is regex always thoroughly disgusting?

Comment: @GrantThomas Actually i agree, i don't think I've ever used regex anywhere. It's disgusting to read and it doesn't feel right or "clean" to me at all..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .Net Core 2.0. & MySQL 5.7

In my current development, I'm assigning the returned value directly into the DOM object like this:

```
DOMControl.value = response.CreatedOn.toString().split(".")[0];
```

I'm returning a [JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) of the resulting object, the resulting JSON arrives with the date value as follows:

```
{
  ...
  createdOn : "2017-11-28T00:43:29.0472483Z"
  ...
}
```

I hope this help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a `DateTime` type to a javascript client, it is converted to a string enclosed as follows `/Date(xxx)/` where `xxx` is the date and time in milliseconds in Unix time. To convert it, you need to remove everything except the `xxx` as follows:

`var date = new Date(parseInt(myCSDateTime.substr(6)));`