# C# DateTime to Javascript parse returns

Tags: javascript, c#

on the aspx I am getting

`date = /Date(1420460565000)/`

I tried to parse it javascript date bject

```
var dateformatted = new Date(date);
```

However when I run it I am getting `Invalid Data`

How do I parse the c# `DateTime` object?

Comment: You should use just the numbers, e.g. something like `new Date(+date.replace(/\D/g,''))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing the C# datetime to javascript datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829521/parsing-the-c-sharp-datetime-to-javascript-datetime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: Come on! This question was asked and answered must be hundred times. Use search, you are not novice here.

Comment: @Fedor—then mark it as a dupe. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Already done. I just shocked by a fact that user that has been registered for 3 years didn't use Google before asking for such a obviously platinum question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var dateformatted = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
```

This works because `substr` function takes out the "/Date(" part, and the parseInt function gets the integer and ignores the ")/" at the end. The resulting number is passed into the Date constructor. Hence a new Date can be created.