# Unix Timestamp conversion to JavaScript wrong output

Tags: javascript

I am storing Unix Timestamp in Firebase server and it is saving as `1417780144675`.

When I am converting [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) the output is:

```
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 11:49:04 GMT
Your time zone: 12/5/2014, 5:19:04 PM GMT+5:30
```

But when I am converting in JavaScript, the output is:

```
Fri Aug 30 46897 15:27:55 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

So output from epochconverter is correct whereas in JavaScript it's coming wrong.

Please how to get correct output using JavaScript.

Comment: Show us your JavaScript code please. We cannot say what you're doing wrong without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: Keep in mind that this type of question has been covered extensively here on StackOverflow. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483787/convert-unix-timestamp-with-a-timezone-to-javascript-date?rq=1

Comment: My guess is that you're looking for: `new Date(1417780144675).toUTCString()`, which returns "Fri, 05 Dec 2014 11:49:04 GMT" (like the middle line of epochconverter).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Thank you i have did in my code var datetime = new Date(data.created_at * 1000); Now its working fine with var datetime = new Date(data.created_at);

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. Next time be sure to include such a code snippet in your question, without it we're playing a guessing game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instanciate a **new** Date:

```
var date = new Date(1417780144675);
```

**Output**:

```
Fri Dec 05 2014 12:49:04 GMT+0100
```

Comment: Okay thank you i did like this var datetime = new Date(data.created_at * 1000); multiplied with 1000. Now it's working fine...