# javascript date from php unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, unix, datetime

In database i have a row with date & time, say `2014-04-16 00:00:00` then I convert that datetime to unix timestamp using

```
strtotime('2014-04-16 00:00:00') * 1000; // result 1397577600000
```

In javascript i am trying to get the hour using the following code

```
var d = new Date(1397577600000); // 1397577600000 from php unix timestamp in previous code
d.getHours(); // return 23
d.getMinutes(); // return 0
```

why `getHours()` return 23 instead of 0? is there any difference between js timestamp and php timestamp?

Comment: because the client side uses the local timezone

Comment: ok, how to overcome this?

Comment: instead of sending a timestamp value, sent a formatted string as the date value like `2014-04-16 00:00:00` the call `new Date('2014-04-16 00:00:00')`

Comment: I can't do that, the unix timestamp used by jQuery flot. that jQuery flot display different time (hour) as i stated above.

Comment: You can also calculate the offset to match the servers timezone. This way you send it the same and store it the same as you have now

Comment: Here is an answer with someone using moment to do something similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/23486254/794102

Answer (score 2):

`Date` objects in javascript will always return values based on the browser's current timezone. So if `d.getHours()` is returning 23 for you, that would suggest your local browser timezone is one hour earlier than UTC (-01:00).

It you want the hours for a `Date` object based on UTC timezone, you can use:

```
d.getUTCHours()
```

#### Follow Up:

Just to throw out some free advice, you could use the following code to deal with your date values from one context to another:

PHP:

```
// Fetched from the db somehow
$datetime_db = '2014-04-16 00:00:00';

// Convert to PHP DateTime object:
$datetime_obj = new DateTime($datetime_db, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Format DateTime object to javascript-friendly ISO-8601 format:
$datetime_iso = $datetime_obj->format(DateTime::W3C);
```

Javascript:

```
var d = new Date('2014-04-16T00:00:00+00:00'); // 2014-04-16T00:00:00+00:00 from PHP in previous code
d.getUTCHours(); // returns 0
```

This keeps the datetime variables in a language-specific object format when being handled in that language, and serializes the value into a string format that all current browsers/languages accept (the international standard ISO-8601).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting `21` here because in Javascript local timezone of the user will be considered to fetch time and date.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on what Arun P Johnny said.

I change the `strtotime` parameter to match my timezone, in this case i changed it to

```
strtotime('2014-04-16 00:00:00 GMT+7') * 1000;
```

hope this help anybody that have the same problem as I.

Comment: this will again fail, if a user has a different timzezone set in their system... try to change the timezone of your system and try

Comment: thanks, i see. but no worries..it's for internal use

Comment: I guess there's no [Daylight Savings](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) in your area...