# How to get utc date from timestamp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a variable containing timestamp ( in seconds generated with php ), I used following code to create date object using javascript

```
var newdate = new Date(arrivalDate);
```

then used following code to get formated date in utc

```
var tempdate = newdate.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+('0' + (newdate.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0' + newdate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
```

It returns me a 1 day before date, not sure how to get utc date from a timestamp.

Comment: are you sure that the time in your local timezone isn't just a time during the previous day in UTC?

Comment: I am 6 hours ahead of utc !

Comment: that means 2nd of April : 12:00:00 (midnight) in your time zone is actually 1st of April 18:00:00 (6pm) in UTC so the code behaves correctly . How do you save your date? Maybe you should send the date in UTC when you save it.

Comment: May b I wrote it wrong but its 6am on my local machine when it 12 am at  utc

Comment: yes, it should be.

Comment: ok so I should use local time then !!

Comment: Can you please provide a full example of the output that you expect and the output that you get?

Comment: it depends on your needs, I was just trying to help you figure out what you might need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript date from php unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668141/javascript-date-from-php-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

var newdate = new Date(arrivalDate);
newdate.toUTCString();