# How to convert epoch to readable dates in Angular to use in Chartist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, epoch

Here I'm getting an array of date/time epochs

```
ApiFactory.getTweetQuotes(the_ticker).then(function(data) {
    // Create epoch array:
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.quotes.length; i++) {                    
        vs.tweet_epochs.push(data.data.quotes[i].start_epoch);
    }

    console.log(vs.tweet_epochs);

    initChart();
    vs.loadingChart = true;
});
```

`vs.tweet_epochs` looks like this consoled out:
[image]

I'm using **[Chartist](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html)** and it's not printing out very pretty at the moment:
[image]

I found this answer here [Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript) however it just added 3 more `0`'s to each epoch instead of convert them into dates.

If you need the Charist code:

```
var initChart = function() {
    var data = {

        labels: vs.tweet_epochs,
        series: [
            vs.tweet_vol
        ]
    };

    // Chart options:
    var options = {
        showPoint: true,
        showArea: true,
        lineSmooth: true,
        fullWidth: true,
        axisX: {
            showGrid: false,
            showLabel: true
        },
        axisY: {
            offset: 40,
            labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
                return '$' + value;
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(TIME)
```

where TIME is the epoch time in MILIseconds, i.e, you should multiply by 1000 if you have a epoch time in seconds.

I don't know how Chartist handle Date objects, but you have a lot of methods to get all readeable parts of a date:

date.getDate               date.getDay                date.getFullYear           date.getHours              date.getMilliseconds       date.getMinutes            date.getMonth
date.getSeconds            date.getTime               date.getTimezoneOffset     date.getUTCDate            date.getUTCDay             date.getUTCFullYear        date.getUTCHours
date.getUTCMilliseconds    date.getUTCMinutes         date.getUTCMonth           date.getUTCSeconds         date.getYear               date.setDate               date.setFullYear
date.setHours              date.setMilliseconds       date.setMinutes            date.setMonth              date.setSeconds            date.setTime               date.setUTCDate
date.setUTCFullYear        date.setUTCHours           date.setUTCMilliseconds    date.setUTCMinutes         date.setUTCMonth           date.setUTCSeconds         date.setYear
date.toDateString          date.toGMTString           date.toISOString           date.toJSON                date.toLocaleDateString    date.toLocaleTimeString    date.toTimeString
date.toUTCString

Answer (score 1):

Consider using momentjs to create a date using the Unix timestamp.  Then you can output it however you like.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/