# Javascript how to convert epoch into local date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting a epoch date into local date:

```
$("time").each(function() {
    var date = $(this).text(); // gives me "1325419200000"
    newDate = new Date(date); // gives me Invalid Date
});
```

html:

```
<td class="date">
    <time datetime="{{date}}">{{date}}</time>
</td>
```

how can i convert epoch date into local date in the format: 'MMM DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A'. how can i achieve this?

Comment: You need to `newDate = new Date(parseInt(date));`.

Comment: Use a library like moment.js. It will save you so much frustration.

Comment: I hope already answered this question. See this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date`Object won't accept String epoch. so you need to convert it to Integer.

[**Check this out**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var epoch = "1325419200000"
var date = new Date(epoch);
// return Invalid Date

date = new Date(parseInt(epoch));
//return Sun Jan 01 2012 21:00:00 GMT+0900
```