# Number of features by day javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a json document that looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "time": 1438342780,
        "title": "Iran's foreign minister calls for world's nuclear weapons states to disarm",
        "author": "Julian Borger",
        "web_id": "world/2015/jul/31/iran-nuclear-weapons-states-disarm-israel"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -77.26526,
          38.90122
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "time": 1438300867,
        "title": "Big bangs over the white cliffs of Dover as unique 1915 artillery gun is fired again",
        "author": "Maev Kennedy",
        "web_id": "world/2015/jul/31/big-bangs-over-white-cliffs-dover-unique-1915-artillery-gun-fired-again"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          1.3,
          51.13333
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to fetch the 'feature' array inside json and return the number of features for a given day. For example, for the data above I would expect something like:

```
{
  "date": 7/31/2015,
  "number": 2
}
```

Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
d3.json('path/to/json', function(json) {
    data = json;
});
```

Fairly new to js and d3 so a bit stumped. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this your date field? `"time": 1438342780`

Comment: I think the date comes from `web_id`.

Comment: yep, sorry the date is associated with the `time` key and is in epoch format.

Comment: Does `"time": 1438342780` represent miliseconds?

Comment: nope only to seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you, it returns an array of object. each object is the object you asked.

```
var a = yourJSONObject, var map = {}, output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.features.length; i++) {
 var ref = new Date(a.features[i].properties.time*1000).toDateString();
 if (map[ref] == undefined) {
  map[ref] = output.push({
    date: ref,
    number: 1
  }) - 1;
 } else 
    output[map[ref]].number++
}

console.log(output) //[ { date: 'Sat Jan 17 1970', number: 2 } ]
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for except that the date parse is returning all dates in 1970 when they are in 2015 according to http://www.epochconverter.com. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take the date parsing from my example.

Comment: Yes, i didn't realize your time reference was an unix timestamp.
Just multiply for 1000. See my edit above @sammy88888888

Answer (score 1):

The critical piece here is that your `time` values are in Epoch time, which means you'll have to convert them to preset dates using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016205/3946177).

Then you can traverse the features array, and track the count for each date.

```
var features = yourJSONObject.features;
var featuresByDate = {};

for (var i = 0, len = features.length; i < len; i++) {
    // find the current feature's date
    var epochTime = features[0].properties.time;
    var date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(epochTime);

    // find the date in 7/31/2015 format
    var dateStr = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

    // count the date for the first time if it has not been counted yet
    if ( ! featuresByDate.hasOwnProperty(dateStr) ) {
         featuresByDate[dateStr] = 1;
    }
    // otherwise, increment its counter
    else {
         featuresByDate[dateStr]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two functions - one to get the [correct date based on the epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016205/1377002), the other to iterate through the features building a temporary object, then iterating through the object to give you an array of date/number objects.

```
function getDate(time) {
  var d = new Date(0);
  d.setUTCSeconds(time);
  return [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}

function getData(data) {
  var obj = data.features.reduce(function(p, c) {
    var date = getDate(c.properties.time);
    p[date] = (p[date] + 1) || 1;
    return p;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (el) {
    return { date: el, number: obj[el] };
  });
}

getData(data);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "date": "7/31/2015",
    "number": 2
  }
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5wu46x07/1/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know D3, but you can do this with straight JS:

```
var json = {
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "time": 1438342780,
            "title": "Iran's foreign minister calls for world's nuclear weapons states to disarm"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "time": 1438300867,
            "title": "Big bangs over the white cliffs of Dover as unique 1915 artillery gun is fired again"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature same date",
        "properties": {
            "time": 1448300867,
            "title": "Big bangs over the white cliffs of Dover as unique 1915 artillery gun is fired again"
        }
    }]
}

var counts = {}

function secondsToDate(seconds) {
    var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toDateString();
}

json.features.reduce((counts, feature) => {
    var date = secondsToDate(feature.properties.time)
    if (counts[date]) {
        counts[date]++
    } else {
        counts[date] = 1
    }
    return counts
}, counts)

console.log(counts) // {'Fri Jul 31 2015': 2, 'Mon Nov 23 2015': 1}
```

<strike>The missing bit is parsing your timestamp into a date.</strike>

Now grouping on dates. Maybe now the downvoter can undo that!

I added an object with a replicated timestamp to highlight the count going up.

Comment: This example works only if you assume all the time properties found fetching JSON are related to the same day.

Comment: Hence the comment "The missing bit is parsing your timestamp into a date."

Comment: Sorry, didn't got you meant this