# Javascript - Converting dates in milliseconds to readable time - missing last 3 digits

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to insert some information in an object into a database. The object is a Stripe object (they process payments). That doesn't really matter; what matters is how they provide the server the 'date' a payment is/was made. They provide it in milliseconds like this:

```
{
    "created": 1489458464
}
```

That's supposed to be the time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC... but its missing the last 3 digits.

So when I want to convert this to a readable time, I simply add 3 zeros to the end like this:

```
var date = 1489458464000;
var date2 = new Date(date);
console.log(date2.toString());

//Output: Mon Mar 13 2017 22:27:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

This seems like an acceptable solution to this problem; the last 3 digits don't seem to change the date/time.

I just want to confirm whether this is okay, or if someone thinks I should be doing something else. Thanks.

Comment: That seems like "created" is in seconds as 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: You may be right...I'm going to check... but that would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api) it is not actually supposed to be in milliseconds, because they are using a [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is expressed as seconds since 1/1/1970. I'd say the most elegant solution would be to take note of that and then just multiply by 1000 in the constructor:

```js
var date2 = new Date(date * 1000) //because Unix timestamps are in seconds
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't look right to me.

In fact, see here:

Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript - Stack Overflow:
 [Convert UTC Epoch to local date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript)