# Issues With Converting Epoch Time to Correct Date

Tags: javascript, time, data-conversion, epoch

I have files with epoch time stamps such as `1564002293050`. Using https://www.epochconverter.com/ this shows `Wednesday, July 24, 2019 9:04:53.050 PM` however my code shows `Mon Apr 06 51531 02:24:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`. Why is this?

Because the times were generated in Unix, I multiplied by 1000 for ms. This value is then displayed.

```
time = 1564002293050;
var dateStamp = new Date(time* 1000);
```

**Edit:** 
Ive referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date) and several similar others. It is good to note that not multiplying it by 1000 will result with `"Invalid Date"`.

**Edit 2:** 
Figure it out. I was parsing the data but looks like I had to convert it to an integer `parseInt(time)` ended up fixing the issue. Sorry for the unrelated solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.write(new Date(1564002293050));
```

Prints `Wed Jul 24 2019 15:04:53 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)` (in my TZ).

Even this outputs the same in HTML, despite not syntactically declaring said variable.

```
time = 1564002293050;
var dateStamp = new Date(time);
document.write(dateStamp);
```

Are you doing this on the browser?  Another Javascript engine?

Comment: I am running this in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: thanks for confirming. It looks like the time I was parsing was still string. Using `parseInt(time)` fixed the issue. Does muliplying a var by 1000 implicity convert the variable to an integer in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The Date constructor takes the epoch time in milliseconds (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Your time is in milliseconds. No need to multiply it by 1000.

Comment: Without multiplying it by 1000 it shows as `"Invalid Date"`

Comment: Where are you executing this, can you provide a reproducable example (maybe jsfiddle) that shows your error?