# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: parsedWeather.sys.sunrise.toLocaleDateString is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
message.channel.send(`

            \nThe Current Weather
            \nLocation: ${parsedWeather.name}, ${parsedWeather.sys.country}
            \nForecast: ${parsedWeather.weather[0].main}
            \nCurrent Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
            \nHigh Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_max - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
            \nLow Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_min - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
            \nSun Rise: ${new Date((parsedWeather.sys.sunrise).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))}
            \nSun Set: ${new Date((parsedWeather.sys.sunset).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))}
            \nTime: ${new Date((parsedWeather.timezone).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))}

            `);
```

I'm not sure how to properly type out my function so I do not receive an error
the "parsedWeather.timezone" gives me a unix timestamp and I need it converted but this does not seem to be working I need it converted to MM/DD/YY Time, Time Zone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC Epoch to local date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date)

Comment: Not sure how to implement this into my code I've tried that but I still get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your `()`'s wrong. Instead of:

```
new Date((parsedWeather.sys.sunrise).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))
```

...do:

```
new Date(parsedWeather.sys.sunrise).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
```

In the first case you're taking a *string* expression `parsedWeather.sys.sunrise` and trying to call a non-existent `toLocaleDateString` method on that. In the second case, you're calling the method on a `Date` expression.

Comment: Kind of what I was looking for but it is displayed as "1/19/1970" with no time, but that's the wrong date so I'm I taking the wrong approach for this?  1588846632 <--- is the sunrise
1588898284 <--- is the sunset
-14400 <----  is the timezone

Comment: Do you want to use `toLocaleString` instead, then? There are lots of string formatting methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Or if those standard ones don't work, you could try using https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Note that `toLocaleString` and the like also let you specify the timezone you want the date represented in.

Comment: Well I tried it and it said "Monday, January 19, 1970 4:20 AM" I'm trying to convert it to today's time

Comment: Looks like your timestamps are _seconds since Unix Epoch_, whereas JavaScript timestamps are in _milliseconds_. If you multiply by 1000 you'll have a better time.