# Convert unix, UTC time from API endpoint to local time in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, datetime

I'm trying to get a weather API setup and wanted to pull in the sunset time. It's in unix,UTC. I've looked up a few discussions but couldn't find something that worked. Here's the API endpoint.

```
"sunset": 1592876160
```

Here's my code:

```
<div>Sunset: {this.state.hits.sunset}</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC Epoch to local date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date)

Comment: Not quite. Still confused about implementation in React.

Comment: React is Javascript. Anything you can do in Javascript, you can do in React. When you set state, do what Keff's answer or the link says.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up putting it after 'render()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a unix timestamp, you can just multiply by 1000, it converts it to milliseconds, then you can create a Date object making use of that timestamp:

```js
const unixTimestamp = this.state.hits.sunset;
const date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1e3); // 1e3 === 1000

// Now you can use built-in methods to convert to a local date.
const localized = date.toLocaleDateString();
```

If you need more customization or want to make more complex operations, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) can help.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up putting it after render()