# Using PHP Timestamp as flipTimer date target for count up timer

Tags: html, jquery, css

Am trying to convert PHP Timestamp date to a format that can be handled by jquery as a target date for count up timer but i cant find a way around.
Here is my code; It only works when i manually edit the target date but when i echo PHP Timestamp then it refuses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flipTimer/css/flipTimer.css">
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="flipTimer/js/jquery.flipTimer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flipTimer">
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="hours"></div>
<div class="minutes"></div>
<div class="seconds"></div>
</div>
<script>
var date1="<?php echo $time; ?>";
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flipTimer').flipTimer({
//count up or count down
direction: 'up',
// the target date that works when i edit manually
date:
'25 July, 2020 07:30:30 ',
//The date format that causes an error
date:
'date1',
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is your PHP time format looks like ?

Comment: What about using an EPOCH date instead? It will solve your issue using less code.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping the time format is in Y/M/D H:M:S

Comment: @NVRM I dont know about EPOCH

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing). Right now for example the time is `1595699245` in seconds, or `1595699245000` in milliseconds since the 1st January 1970. This allow to easily share a date and roll math, without messing with the month and such. Then in js do this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016205/2494754 Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
var date1="<?php echo $time; ?>";
```

You are defining `date1` as a string however, when you instantiate a date object with a timestamp it should be an integer. Also remember the php timestamp is going to be in seconds while JavaScript expects milliseconds.
Try this:

```
var date1 = <?php echo $time; ?>;
// or
var date1 = <?php echo time() * 1000; ?>;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.flipTimer').flipTimer({
    direction: 'up',
    date: date1,
  });
});
```