# How to convert epoch timestamp to normal date time format using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

**Epoch Time Stamp:**

1598944721950

**Output Required:**

dd/mm/yyy hh:mm AM/PM

Comment: `new Date(1598944721950)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC Epoch to local date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const epochToFullDateTime = (epochValue) => {
    let dateObject = new Date(epochValue);
    let timeStamp = dateObject.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
    });
    const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { year: "numeric" }).format(dateObject);
    const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { month: "numeric" }).format(dateObject);
    const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { day: "2-digit" }).format(dateObject);
    
    let fullDateTime = `${da}/${mo}/${ye} ${timeStamp}`; 
    return fullDateTime;
};
let time = epochToFullDateTime(1598944721950);
console.log(time);
```