# Javascript Convert BigInt to Datetime and Format

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime, bigint

I have a method that returns the timestamp which is a bigint.

The built in Date method only accepts a number to create a date time. Is there another function or method that can take a bigint and convert that to a date.

Essentially something similar to Java's DateTimeFormatter class.

Also if possible is there a way to format the date as a string with the pattern "yyyyMMdd" looking for something similar to Java's

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern
```

the timestamp is milliseconds since epoch time

```
let time = 1630017759934
```

Comment: The answer is yes to all your questions. Can you share your code that you have tried and errors you have come across? When you say you have a `bigint` which is a timestamp, can you elaborate with some samples too?

Comment: What kind of date are you saving if you need bigint size?
Unix epoch time size is 10 digits (13 if you messure milliseconds).

If you have some extreme requirement for small time-messurement in unix epoch time and only need yyyyMMdd then you can always just divide your time to make it smaller and convert it to a number first.  
E.e. milliseconds persision to second persision.  
`const t = Math.floor(1630012381123 / 1000);`  
`const d = new date(t);`

Comment: I believe I can cast the timestamp from bigint to a number given the unix epoch time (milliseconds).  Just now wondering what is the best way to format the date to the required pattern

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date)

Comment: The number type can represent all integers of up to 53 bits exactly. Your timestamp has at most 42 bits, so there is plenty of room.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: For formatting looking for something similar to Java's DateTimeFormat.forPattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that timestamp you could just use regular number, it's size is 15 and with millisecond persision you only use size 13.

Here's some example code that might work for you:

```
const time = 1630017759934;
const timeInSeconds = Math.floor(time/1000);
const d = new date(timeInSeconds);
const dateFormatted = `${date.getFullYear()}${(date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}${date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
```

Comment: I tested this instead I believe it works as well. 

```
const time = 1630017759934;
const d = new Date(Number(time));

Is getMonth and getDay zero based which is why the +1 is needed?

Comment: @TeddyDong— 1630017759934 is not an [ECMAScript BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), it's just a number so `new Date(time)` is sufficient (returns a Date for 2021-08-26T22:42:39.934Z). Also, code in comments is wrapped in single escapes: \``code`\`. :-) Yes, months are zero indexed as are days, 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.

Comment: @TeddyDong: It's like RobG says. Did this answer your question? If so, please accept it as the answer using the checkmark on the left. If not, is there something you still need help with?

Comment: @RobG So getDate isn't what I need since it is day of week, is there a way to get the actual day (26) from 2021-08-26T22:42:39.934Z

Comment: @TeddyDong: Updated my post with the correct function.
The one you are looking for is getDate.
The example code should work now.

Comment: @Wirde—you also need to pad single digit months and days with a leading zero.

Comment: so last thing I am using toDate() from 

    `new Date(1630017759934)`

however the day becomes 27 instead of 26. Is there a way to fix the timestamp or timezone? getUTCDate() also returns 27

Comment: So with timestamp and Date you won't need the +1 for the `getDate()` method only `getMonth()`. Thanks

Comment: @RobG: Ah ofcourse, i updated the example with that in mind.
TeddyDong: Try the new example code, should give you a date like 20210803 instead of 202183.