# Wrong Time Zone Offset Returned by Javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I am using the following code to get a datetime at a specified time zone. The date and time is returned correctly except for the the time zone offset.

Ex: in the below snippet it returns time zone offset (GMT+2) instead of the desired one (GMT+5 at New Delhi)

How to fix it to return the same offset as the specified time zone?

```js
const options = {
  dateStyle: "long",
  timeStyle: "long",
};

const dateTimeAtNewDelhi = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" }))
 
 
document.querySelector('#timezone-date-time').innerHTML = dateTimeAtNewDelhi.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
```

```css
#timezone-date-time{
  font-size:1.5em;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="timezone-date-time">

</div>
```

Comment: you have to use epoch time for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date

Comment: @tarikmetink - no, that doesn't address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt to create `dateTimeAtNewDelhi`, it would appear that you are expecting the `Date` object to retain the time zone.  It will not.

The `Date` object does not carry any time zone information with it whatsoever.  It is simply a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.

Thus, the way you *fix* it, is by specifying the time zone during output.

```js
const options = {
  dateStyle: "long",
  timeStyle: "long",
  timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"
};

const dateTime = new Date();
 
 
document.querySelector('#timezone-date-time').innerHTML = dateTime.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
```

```css
#timezone-date-time{
  font-size:1.5em;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="timezone-date-time">

</div>
```

Note that your original approach tried re-parsing to account for time zone, which is a common mistake, covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) - along with other approaches that *do* work, such as using a time zone aware object from a library, rather than `Date`.