# Postman change unix time in microseconds to datetime

Tags: postman, data-conversion, epoch

I have a JSON response which includes unix timestamp in microseconds. I want to either:
a. Add a field to the response so that it shows the date+time; or
b. Change the field itself to be date+time.

Whichever is easier, but preferably a. The format I need is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.ssssss

I was reviewing the following threads but I don't really understand them:

[Convert UTC Epoch to local date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date)

https://community.postman.com/t/convert-datetime-format-of-response-from-epoch-to-datetime/35320

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman-flows/reference/working-with-date-and-time/

And I tried looking at FQL documentation but that was too in-depth too.

This is part of an example response:

```
"SequenceNumber": 230901153510049870,
"Trade": {
        "LastPrice": 73.6,
        "LastSize": 53798,
        "Timestamp": 1693582510115510,
```

And I would like it to look something like:

```
"SequenceNumber": 230901153510049870,
"Trade": {
        "LastPrice": 73.6,
        "LastSize": 53798,
        "Timestamp": 1693582510115510,
      **  "DateTime": 01/09/2023 15:35:10.115510,**
```

Full example output:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "Outcome": "Success",
    "Ticks": [
        {
            "SequenceNumber": 230814040000019593,
            "IsExtendedHour": false,
            "Ask": null,
            "Bid": null,
            "Trade": {
                "LastPrice": 74700.0,
                "LastSize": 100,
                "Timestamp": 1691985600000000,
                "OptionalFields": {
                    "TradeId": "58850000",
                    "size": "100",
                    "price": "74700",
                    "style": "-1",
                    "type": "0",
                    "minorcurrencytype": "-1",
                    "currency": "964",
                    "marketsession": "0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "SequenceNumber": 230814040000019591,
            "IsExtendedHour": false,
            "Ask": null,
            "Bid": null,
            "Trade": {
                "LastPrice": 74700.0,
                "LastSize": 200,
                "Timestamp": 1691985600000000,
                "OptionalFields": {
                    "TradeId": "58840000",
                    "size": "200",
                    "price": "74700",
                    "style": "-1",
                    "type": "0",
                    "minorcurrencytype": "-1",
                    "currency": "964",
                    "marketsession": "0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "DepthOfBooks": []
}
```

Comment: You can't modify the response in Postman as this is controlled by the API code.  (Are you in control of the API? Can changes be made to the response code?)  In Postman, you can parse the response, and then use the moment library to change the date format for that value.  You can then console log the updated response or maybe use the visualizer (but you can't change the actual response).

Comment: So the only place that I would be able to see it is in the console logs? (No I don't have access to the API.)

So out of interest what does the FQL do? It sounded like you could manipulate the data.

Comment: I haven't used the Flows Query Language, but that won't be able to change a response.  The output object would appear to be fairly customizable but this sounds like a sledge hammer to crack a nut.  I would recommend trying the visualize tab in Postman first.  If you provide an example response with at least two records, I can share the visualizer code using moment to format that date.

Comment: Thank you. I have added it to the main question as it was too long to post as a comment.

Comment: Can you clarify which fields you want to show in the visualiser?  The Sequence Number and Timestamp, or are there other fields you want to see?  Can you also confirm the date format.  I've got "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss", what are the last six sssss meant to be?

Comment: It's only the timestamp please. It is in microseconds so the last 6 digits are the fraction of seconds. e.g. 1693582510115510 = 01/09/2023 15:35:10.115510 UTC, where 115510 is the number of microseconds. I'll take a look at the FQL. So many thanks for this.

Comment: In that case, the visualizer I provided should be accurate as I've split the fractions of seconds as moment didn't like it (and produced a date somewhere in the year 5000.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, I'm looping through the parsed response updating the Timestamp before its consumed in the Visualizer.

I had to slice the timestamp to get it to show as you requested.  (I'm still not sure what the last six digits are).

```
const response = pm.response.json();

var moment = require('moment');

response.Ticks.forEach(obj => {
    let utcMicroseconds = obj.Trade.Timestamp.toString();
    let utcSeconds = parseInt(utcMicroseconds.slice(0, 10)) * 1000;
    let remainder = parseInt(utcMicroseconds.slice(-6));
    let d = moment(utcSeconds).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    obj.Trade.Timestamp = d + "." + remainder;
});

var template = `

    <style type="text/css">
        .tftable {font-size:14px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #87ceeb;border-collapse: collapse;}
        .tftable th {font-size:18px;background-color:#87ceeb;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #87ceeb;text-align:left;position:sticky;top:0;}
        .tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
        .tftable td {font-size:14px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #87ceeb;}
        .tftable tr:hover {background-color:#e0ffff;}
    </style>
    
    <table class="tftable" border="1">

        <tr>
            <th>Sequence Number</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>

        {{#each response}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{SequenceNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{Trade.Timestamp}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}

    </table>

`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: response.Ticks
});
```

This produces the following in the Visualizer.  (Please note, the time is showing my timezone, so its an hour out).

[image]