# Get URL Path without last segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How can I get the URL Path of the current site, but without the last segment:

```
http://www.domain.com/first/second/last
```

I only need `http://www.domain.com/first/second` … with jQuery (or only JavaScript)

Comment: `var firstpart = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"))`

Comment: @mplungjan: please add your Comment as a Answer, this one works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last segment of URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using pop and URL api

this assumes the URL is not likely to change

I use [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.URL) since that is what is recommended

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.example.com/first/second/last"); // new URL(document.URL)
let path = url.pathname.split("/");
path.pop(); // remove the last
url.pathname = path.join("/")
console.log(url)
```

Older answers: As requested by OP - with changes from comment

```js
const url = "http://www.example.com/first/second/last", // document.URL, 
    shortUrl=url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(shortUrl)
```

Here is an alternative

```js
const url = new URL("http://www.example.com/first/second/last"),
      shortUrl = `${url.protocol}//${url.hostname}${url.pathname.slice(0,url.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"))}`

console.log(shortUrl)
```

Comment: does work with: `var url = document.location.href, shortURL = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));`

Comment: but document.location.href is deprecated for document.URL, hence I use that

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/KZsEW

Try the following for all browsers:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/first/second/last";  // or var url = document.URL;
var subUrl = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"))

alert(subUrl);
​
```

The `lastIndexOf()` method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified value in a string.

> Note: The string is searched from the end to the beginning, but
>   returns the index starting at the beginning, at postion 0.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: You're using lastIndexOf on a string, not on an Array, so there is no need to modify the array prototype.

Comment: Sorry! I deleted to stop any more confusion, I was confused myself.

Comment: Really neat answer as it's essentially a one-liner that can be used in array.map()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant of solutions, but you just want the substring up to the last slash, or second to last if the last character is a slash. Here I first take the part of the URL that appears after the protocol (http:// or https://) so that on for example http://stackoverflow.com it returns http://stackoverflow.com.

```
    var url = document.URL.split('://');
    var last_slash;
    var result;
    if (url[1].charAt(url[1].length - 1) === '/') {
      url[1] = url[1].substring(0, url[1].length - 1);
    }
    last_slash = url[1].lastIndexOf('/');
    result = url[0] + '://' + ((last_slash !== -1) ? url[1].substring(0, last_slash) : url[1]);
```

edit: jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CV6d4/

Comment: You're already using split, so why not split the string on '/' instead of '://', pop the last item from the array and join them again. http://jsfiddle.net/8chxf/

Comment: You'd have to tweak it to get the corner cases, i.e. if you add a "/" at the end of the URL in your solution it doesn't work, and it also doesn't work on "http://www.domain.com".

Comment: document.location is deprecated for document.URL - window.location.href is also valid.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. A more robust solution might worth the extra code.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, didn't know that document.location was deprecated -- good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://www.domain.com/first/second/last';
for(var i=url.length-1; i>=0;i--){
    if(url[i]!='/'){
        url= url.substr(0,i);
    }
    else{
        alert(url);
        break;
    }
}
```