# tacking specific value from url form jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, url-parsing

i have one url Like http://www.example.com/wall/post/1234568929842184
now i want to take the number after post/ from my url from javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758173/1846192).

In your case:

```
var href = window.location.href;
window.alert(href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Comment: oops...i search it since 1 hour but didn't find...so ..by the way Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend.. [http://www.google.com.au/search?q=get+last+part+of+url+javascript](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=get+last+part+of+url+javascript)