# jQuery get last part of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, get

I have a series of pages where I need to get a specific code for a button.
I want to put the code which is in the url into a variable with jQuery.

An example URL is www.example.com/folder/code/12345/

I want to get the number part in a variable called (siteCode)

Thanks in advance for any answers.

jquery / Pseudo code:

```
var siteCode;

// start function
function imageCode(){
     siteCode // equals number part of URL
     $('.button').attr('src', 'http:www.example.com/images/'+siteCode+'.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var str="url";

str.split("/")[3]
```

you can use split

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following code to get the last part of the url.:

```
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: You realise the `lastIndexOf('/')` occurs as the last character of the URL/string?

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest:

```
var URI = 'www.example.com/folder/code/12345/',
    parts = URI.split('/'),
    lastPart = parts.pop() == '' ? parts[parts.length - 1] : parts.pop();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tDbHf/).

Comment: Using `.pop()` confuses things as it's destructive and changes the `parts[]` array. If your URI does not have a trailing slash, this fails to return '12345' and instead returns 'code'. Using this version is more straight-forward: `lastPart = parts[parts.length-1] !== '' ? parts[parts.length-1] : parts[parts.length-2];`

Answer (score 3):

There is one best way to take last part of URL is like following which generally has been used in real implementation.

There are Some **loopholes** in previously given answer was:

1.Consider what if there is a url like `www.example.com/folder/code/12345` (Without '/' forward slash) Than none of the above code will work as per expectation.

2.Consider if folder hierarchy increases like `www.example.com/folder/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder/code/12345`

```
$(function () {
     siteCode = getLastPartOfUrl('www.example.com/folder/code/12345/');
});

var getLastPartOfUrl =function($url) {
    var url = $url;
    var urlsplit = url.split("/");
    var lastpart = urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1];
    if(lastpart==='')
    {
        lastpart = urlsplit[urlsplit.length-2];
    }
    return lastpart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

```
var url = "www.example.com/folder/code/12345";
  var checkExt = /\d$/i.test(url);
  if (checkExt) {
      alert("Yup its a numeric");
  } else {
      alert("Nope");
  }
```