# Get last value in URL path string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

Given an href like:

http://localhost:8888/#!/path/somevalue/needthis

How can I get the last value in the path string (aka: "needthis")?

I tried using `window.location.pathname`, which gives "/".

I also tried using Angular's `$location`, which doesn't provide the last value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can try this:

```
s="http://localhost:8888/#!/path/somevalue/needthis"
var final = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(final)
```

Answer (score 3):

window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()

Answer (score 1):

what I would do is make a function that takes an index of what part you want.. that way you can get any part anytime

```
getPathPart = function(index){
    if (index === undefined)
        index = 0;

    var path = window.location.pathname,
        parts = path.split('/');

    if (parts && parts.length > 1)
        parts = (parts || []).splice(1);

    return parts.length > index ? parts[index] : null;
}
```

with this you can of course make changes like a getLastIndex flag that when true you can return that..

```
getPathPart = function(index, getLastIndex){
    if (index === undefined)
        index = 0;

    var path = window.location.pathname,
        parts = path.split('/');

    if (parts && parts.length > 1)
        parts = (parts || []).splice(1);

    if(getLastIndex){
        return parts[parts.length - 1]
    }  

    return parts.length > index ? parts[index] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using angularjs, you can use:

```
$location.path().split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the string, then do a substring from the beginning of the reversed string to the first occurrence of "/" .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var string = "http://localhost:8888/#!/path/somevalue/needthis";
var segments = string.split("/");
var last = segments[segments.length-1];
console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression for this:

```
var fullPath = 'http://localhost:8888/#!/path/somevalue/needthis',
    result = fullPath.match(/(\w*)$/gi),
    path = (result)? result[0] : '';
```

this way `path` would have the last chunk of text from the URL