# How to get the last part of url AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

How to build the function in AngularJS to chceck the last part of the url?

My examples:

`#/menu1/123/edit`

`#/menu2/444/create/new`

`#/menu3/sumbenu1/333/create/new`

`#/menu4/submenu2/subsubmenu1/subsubsubmenu1/543/edit`

The thing is:

`123` `444` `333` `543` are the ID's which are generated outside Angular

I need to check the last parts of my url: `/edit` or `/create/new`.

The length of the url will be different (number of `/` inside url).

I have a controller in Angular to get the url:

```
.controller('urlCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.location = $location;
    $scope.hashPath = "#" + $rootScope.location.path().toString();
}]);
```

I'm adding the `#` character to the url because later I'm comparing it with my JSON.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758173/4713535) but it didn't work (I also checked another solutions from this topic and nothing happened).

**Any ideas?**

**EDIT:**

Or how to check just the `edit` or `create` inside the url?

My solution is:

```
var path = $location.path();
var multisearch = path.search(/create|edit|new/);
console.log("multisearch: " + multisearch);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
window.alert(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

You could get the current URL by using: window.location.href 
Then you only need to get the part after the last '/'

Answer (score 1):

More efficient way:

```
location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
```

In case of `http://example.com/firstdir/seconddir/thirddir?queryparams#hash`; it will give you `thirddir`

- `pathname` will keep only the part of url after domain name and
  before query params
- `split` will explode the url into array separated by `/`
- `slice` will give you array containing only the last item
- `[0]` will you last item as a string (in contrast to item of an
  array)