# angular regex to get last parts of an url

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I would like to get the last parts of an url in order to know in which "case" I am : edit, add, delete or list. Moreover, I would like to know what is the page where I am.

Here some examples :

```
xxxxx/xxxx/items/add

Page: items
case: add
```

---

```
xxxxx/xxxx/items/edit/:id

Page : items
case: edit
id: xxxx
```

---

```
xxxxx/xxxx/items

Page : items
case: list
```

For now, I can determine if I'm edit or add case by using includes function. I can also get the last part of my url but, only the last part. So if i'm on edit case, I only get the id.

Thank you very much for any advices/solutions !

Comment: Are you using the Angular router?

Comment: You definitely need to have a look at [this](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

Comment: I'm using the router.events and RoutesRecognized. From here, I get the url

Comment: May be a possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556069/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-url-angularjs