# Extracting the end of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I am trying to extract the last part of a YouTube URL so that I can embed video into my desired container. After looking around on Stack I believe I am on the right track.

If anyone is able to help me that would be much appreciated. Please see my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thumbFetch = $('.js-thumb');
    var youTubeID = thumbFetch.val().substring(thumbFetch.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    thumbFetch.change(function() {
        if(thumbFetch.val().length > 0) {
            $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youTubeID + '?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        } else {
            $('.content-img-wrapper').empty();
            $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<div class="content-img-placeholder"></div>');
        }
     });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle so that you can see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/rxa0d7va/

I am getting an error that says 'thumbFetch.lastIndexOf is not a function'. I don't understand this as I am following the answer of this question:
[Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

If anyone is able to point me in the direction of how I have gone wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed referencing the value of `thumbFetch`.

Have `thumbFetch.val().lastIndexOf('/') + 1` instead of `thumbFetch.lastIndexOf('/') + 1`

Comment: No problem, and you need to have that line inside `onchange` so that `youTubeID` will be updated.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @Griffith.