# How to Access ngRoute Param from Scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code which routes some of my URLs:

```
        .when('/patient/:patient', {
            templateUrl: 'views/patient.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'dashboard'
        })
```

I am looking to access the :patient information from the scope. What is the most direct method to access that information from the scope?

In other words, how do I know which patient the URL is at?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url - what you can do is parse the whole url, find the last `/` and extract what's after that character.

Comment: thanks but this isn't the answer I'm looking for. Why does AngularJS make us specify :patient instead of :*?

Answer (score 1):

Just inject `$routeParams` into your controller and assign `$routeParams['patient']`to a property of your scope.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?