# Retrieve last part of clicked URL in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, a variable called `{{Click URL}}` retrieves the full name of the link clicked (http://www.example.com/path/path/file.pdf)

I'm trying to create a variable that will retrieve everything after the last `/` (file.pdf). I guess I need to create a Custom Javascript variable, but all my attempts so far have failed.

Amongst other things, I tried this solution: [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Code looked something like this:

```
function () { 
   var href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   window.alert(href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
   return href;
}
```

Also tried this: http://www.apasters.com/blog/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-examples/

Code looked like this:

```
function () {
   var value={{Click URL}}.split("/");
   return value[1];
}
```

Comment: What are some of the things you have tried so far? Please post your code attempts. Looks like you will need to do some string parsing, but that should be fairly easy, if you're just after the filename and extension.

Comment: Thanks @nyuen I've added some info below

Comment: Have you tried just using custom event code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in your custom JS variable:

```
function(){
   var cu = {{Click URL}};
   var l = cu.split("/").length;
   return cu.split("/")[l-1];
}
```

This would return the last part of the clicked URL (which is the file name plus extension).

Answer (score 0):

There are component types "Query" and "Fragment" in Google Tag Manager also, which would get last part of URL after the ? or #