# How do I get part of a url using javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, instagram-api, callbackurl

I have a url that looks like this
https://adv-web-final-robneal28.c9users.io/index.html?code=7eba04a6a83f4d5aac30afec6a44b61

its being generated with as part of the instagram implicit oauth. I need to be able grab the code part of the url (7eba04a6a83f4d5aac30afec6a44b61) and store in a variable to use else where in my code. I have to do this in javascript.

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url

Comment: I had created a utility function that might help. [QS to Object](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/neagdcyt/). This will fetch all query parameters and return an object. Also you should read about [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).