# asp.net ,how to get last part of url as webPage heading

Tags: asp.net

How do i get the last part of url after Categoery/?

**url: http://localhost:3333/Category/Laptops%2c%20PC%2c%20HardDrives**

I've used the following code to get the url, and used it as heading of page

```
 <h2><%: Page.Request.RawUrl.ToString ()%> </h2>
```

However I get  the following result:  /Category/Laptops, PC, HardDrives

I want to get following result: Laptops, PC, HardDrives

Comment: if you google the title..... `<h2><%: Page.Request.RawUrl.ToString().Substring(Page.Request.RawUrl.ToString().LastIndexOf("/")+1)%> </h2>`

Comment: Thanks H.Mikhaeljan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Comment: It's a duplicate, but in javascript. This is looking for a C#/.NET answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758173/609731)

```js
window.alert(this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```