# how to I retrieve last part of URL and use it in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is example of URL from which I want to extract the last part which is name of the person.

```
 yourdomain.com/?n=PERSON .
```

I want the part after

```
" ?n= "
```

Then use this person name on the same HTML page. So I will be showing this person name on the web page. The web page is in HTML.
DO I need java script or PHP code?
Thanks

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you need javascript (or PHP, as D.Dimitrov said). Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url

Comment: With PHP: echo $_GET['n'];

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to this. how do I use "echo $_GET['n']; " . I mean where do I put this. Can you please give me the code how to use? Do i need to change page.html to page.php?

Comment: java's not javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after the domain, path and file is called Query String.

You can access the data within it by using php

in the html:

```
<?php echo $_GET['n']; ?>
```

This example uses your own example. domain.com/path/file.php?n=Jim_Williams

Comment: So this code will get the query string. eg. - Jim_Williams . Then how do I post it on the web page. what would be code to show this query string on web page.

Comment: The echo posts it. You just have to copy that line and place it where you want it to show

Comment: GOT it WORKING. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JimWilliams Sure thing. Please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` for this purpose

```
var url_string = window.location.href; // www.test.com?n=Person
var url = new URL(url_string);
var paramValue = url.searchParams.get("n");
alert(paramValue);
```

Put this code under `<script>` tag and you can also run it in your `.html` file.
You can also use `php` code to get `$_GET` request. For this purpose you must have to make a file with `.php` extension and type code as below

```
<?php
 echo $_GET['n'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access URL parametrs in php by using 'GET' method.

By taking your example, you can do it by using

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['n'];
?>
```

You can use $name anywhere on page where you want to display the name like below

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this `<?= $_GET['n'] ?>` which's equivalent to `<?php echo $_GET['n'] ?>`