# How to get parameter after slash using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the parameters after slash in the url. For example the facebook profile url is like this `https://www.facebook.com/username`

I want to get username parameter from the url and act on it. I am sorry if its a duplicate question or not but I could not find the solution for it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `split('/').pop()` with backslash:

```js
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/username';
var username = url.split('/').pop();
console.log(username);
```