# How to get a value or a part from url?

Tags: javascript

I have a URL as follows
`http://localhost:8080/list/PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ`

I need "PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ" from this url. How to do this by javascript?

Comment: take a look nodejs and url-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and get the last value from array.

```js
let str = 'http://localhost:8080/list/PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ'
let res = str.split('/').pop()

console.log(res)
```

Another way can be using `lastIndexOf()` and `slice()`

```js
let str = 'http://localhost:8080/list/PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ'
let res = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

console.log(res)
```

You can also use regular expression.

```js
let str = 'http://localhost:8080/list/PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ'
let res = /\/[^\/]+$/.exec(str)[0].slice(1)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: the first solution that you give, I think it should be `res[res.length -1]` or  `res.pop()`

Answer (score 1):

Just split by slash(`/`) using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and get last part from the array using [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method.

```js
let str = 'http://localhost:8080/list/PEPPR_BDCAREUGWJ'
let res = str.split('/').pop();

console.log(res)
```