# How to take a part of a carrent url with cypress and RegEx

Tags: regex, url, automated-tests, cypress

I can get current Url and pass it to const variable.

My URL like this
http://bla/bla/ID

I want to take ID and pass it to const again.

This is my code.

```
    cy.url().then(url => {
        const currentURL = url;
    });
```

Pls help me, How can I do it with cypress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url)

Comment: No, My question is different, Thanks

Comment: really it's not different the answer you have accepted is simply JavaScript manipulating a string - nothing to do with cypress. Most (if not all) of the answers in the question [Last segment of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url) also apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not necessarily searching for a solution within Cypress, but within Javascript. What you can do is this:

```js
  const currentURL = 'http://bla/bla/ID'.split('/')
  const id = currentURL[4]
cy.log(id)
```

What does it do?

- `currentURL` contains the full URL
- `split()` will split the URL per every '/'. So you'll end up with an array with values 'http:', '', 'bla', 'bla' and 'ID'.
- `id` will hold the actual ID part of the URL
- `log()` will print the value of 'id' in your Cypress logging.