# Jquery: get query value from beatified url

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting

Is there any way to get the `id` from a beautified URL? I have a beautified an URL with `.htaccess`:

Old URL: `https://example.com/products.php?id=UDn4LdBa3yy`

new URL: `https://example.com/product/UDn4LdBa3yy`

Now I need to get the `id` form the URL with javascript. But a standard javascript function to split the URL at the `=` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please refer the below article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url

Comment: @Sanyam That wouldn't work if the user puts something in the URL or when I have another query string in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract last part of url after "/" using subString() in javascript.
If there is another query string that follows, include the index of the '?' character, otherwise omit the index. See below:

```
var newURL="https://example.com/product/UDn4LdBa3yy";
var queryString=newURL.indexOf('?');
var id;
if(queryString!=-1){
    id=newURL.substring(newURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1,queryString);
}
else{
    id=newURL.substring(newURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
console.log(id);
```

Comment: If this would not fit one of your use cases, provide an example of when it would not and I can edit the answer.