# Javascript - grab page name from url whether trailing slash or not

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this is stumping me. I need to grab the 'page' of a site. In my dev environment there is no trailing slash but on the staging server a trailing slash gets added. So, how do I return `"page-name"` regardless of if there's a trailing slash?

(Vanilla or jquery)

```
www.website.com/page-name
www.website.com/page-name/
```

My long solution... is there a shorter way?

```
let { href } = window.location;
let lastChar = href.substr(-1);
let ref;
if (lastChar === "/") {
  ref = href.slice(0, -1);
} else {
  ref = href;
}
let pageName = ref.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: Get the string after the last `/`; if it's empty, get the string after the penultimate `'/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last segment of URL in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url-in-jquery)

Comment: use const pageName= window.location.href.split('/')[1]??'home'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.pathname` to get the path, then split by `/` and get the second item in the resulting array:

```js
const result = location.pathname.split("/")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex possibly? get the last capture group.

```
let { href } = window.location;
const match = href.match(/\/([\w-]+)/g);
console.log(match[match.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
const url=window.location.href.split('\//')[1]??'home'
```

Comment: @moshen Parvar that returns the whole URL...