# How to extract a part of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures/00cb3b0b-45d5-486b-8f33-0fa3bf2285ff.jpg`

And I want to extract the string after the last `/` which will be `00cb3b0b-45d5-486b-8f33-0fa3bf2285ff.jpg`

How can I extract the last part of this string and store it in a variable ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last segment of URL in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url-in-jquery). `filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`

Comment: `str.split('/')[str.length-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted the last part of string like this :

```
mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```