# How to take a part of a carrent url with cypress/javascript

Tags: javascript, url, cypress

how can i extract the id from this link ? `.localhost/survey/20?vbpCategoryId`

my code is:

```
cy.url().then(URL => {
  const current_url = URL.split('/');
  cy.log(current_url[nr]);

  cy.wrap(current_url[nr]).as('alias');
```

if it was between "/" it was easy but in this case it is between "/" and "?"

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last segment of URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

If your URL will always be formed similar to as you explained, we can use `.split()` and `.pop()` to easily get this ID.

`.pop()` takes the last item off of an array and returns it.

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  const splitUrl = url.split('/');
  const ending = splitUrl.pop();
  const id = ending.split('?')[0];
  // code using id
})
```

I've been overly verbose in laying out each line, but you could theoretically combine it into one line as:

```js
const id = url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];
```

We could even simplify this a little bit, by using `cy.location('pathname')`.

```js
// assuming url is something like http://localhost:1234/survey/20?vbpCategoryId
cy.location('pathname').then((pathname) => {
  /** 
  * `pathname` yields us just the path, excluding the query parameters and baseUrl 
  * (in this case, `?vbpCategoryId` and `http://localhost:1234`), 
  * so we would have a string of `/survey/20`.
  */
  const id = pathname.split('/').pop();
});
```

Comment: omg i have never got a better explanation then this one. it was very useful thanks!

Comment: Assuming `pathname` returns `/survey/20`, you could probably simplify it a bit by using `cy.location('pathname')`.

Comment: @jjhelguero Ahh true, I completely forgot about `cy.location`. I'll add that as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the `.replace` method with a regex to extract just the number from your url and then save it like this:

```js
cy.url().then((URL) => {
  const id = +URL.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') //Gets the id 20 and changes it to a number
  cy.wrap(id).as('urlId')
})

cy.get('@urlId').then((id) => {
  //access id here
})
```

In case you don't want the `id` to be converted into a number you can simply remove the `+` from `URL.replace` like this:

```js
cy.url().then((URL) => {
  const id = URL.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') //Gets the id 20
  cy.wrap(id).as('urlId')
})

cy.get('@urlId').then((id) => {
  //access id here
})
```