# How to extract the filename of the URL of the current document path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to extract the current file name in Javascript without any parameters.

```
$(location).attr('href').match(/([a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+\.\w+)$/);
var current_path = RegExp.$1;
if ((current_path == 'index.html') || ...) {
  // something here
}
```

But it doesn't work at all when you access like *http://example.com/index.html?lang=ja*. Sure before the file name will be changed at random.

Any idea?

Comment: Wow, you need to learn some javascript. `$(location).attr('href')` === `location.href` javascript is a precursor to jQuery, not the other way around

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761

Comment: @Kei: I edited the title to reflect that you are asking about the current path only. I hope that's OK.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're looking for the last item in the path, try this:

```
var current_path = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

This:

```
window.location.pathname
```

will give you something like:

```
"/questions/6543242/how-to-extract-the-filename-of-url-in-javascript"
```

Then the `.split()` will split the string into an Array, and `.pop()` will give you the last item in the Array.

Comment: @npe you are wrong. `location.pathname` does not return query/hash params. Ex. `http://somehost:8080/web/path/to/yourfile.txt?something=1222&another=more#andAHash`   is your `location.href` then `location.pathname` returns `'/web/path/to/yourfile.txt'`

Comment: Note that this answer solves the asker's niche case, but doesn't support all valid URLs.

Comment: I like that you didn't directly answer the OP's question. The answer is good and probably more likely to stick if you need to engage your brain rather than copy and paste like most cases. +1

Answer (score 14):

```
function filename(path){
    path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+ 1);
    return (path.match(/[^.]+(\.[^?#]+)?/) || [])[0];
}

console.log(filename('http://example.com/index.html?lang=ja'));

// returned value: 'index.html'
```

Answer (score 10):

The filename of a URL is everything following the last `"/"` up to one of the following: 1.) a `"?"` (beginning of *URL query*), or 2.) a `"#"` (beginning of *URL fragment*), or 3.) the end of the string (if there is no query or fragment).

This tested regex does the trick:

`.match(/[^\/?#]+(?=$|[?#])/);`

Answer (score 1):

There is a [URL.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) library that makes it very easy to work with URLs. I recommend it!

**Example**

```
var uri = new URI('http://example.org/foo/hello.html?foo=bar');
uri.filename(); // => 'hello.html'
```

Comment: You are not seriously recommending a library for this are you? That's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

your regex isn't correct. Instead try to be more specific:

```
.match(/([a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})[\?\$]/);
```

says:

find any number of alphanumeric or hypens`[a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+` before a fullstop that has between 2 and 4 alphabetic characters `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` that combefore either the end (`\$`) or a question mark (`\?`)

tested on:

```
("http://www.example.com/index.html?lang=ja").match(/([a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})[\?\$]/);
var current_path = RegExp.$1;
alert(current_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something more simple:

```
var url = "http://google.com/img.png?arg=value#div5"
var filename = url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0];
```

Result:

```
filename => "img.png"
```