# Getting parts of a URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently on `www.google.com/folder/folder/archive.php` and using `window.location` to determine that. I actually want to target `/archive.php`, and nothing else.

Is there something that could achieve that?

```
window.location.host = "www.google.com"

window.location.pathname = "folder/folder/archive.php"

???? = "/archive.php
```

Comment: You should be able to easily extract that form the pathname... :)

Comment: Just use: pathname.substr(pathname .lastIndexOf('/'))

Comment: "I'm currently on `www.google.com/folder/folder/archive.php`" I doubt that. [`example.com`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) is reserved for exactly this reason :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract the filename of URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543242/how-to-extract-the-filename-of-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Oh Gareth! I'll remember that for next time. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :)

```
console.log(window.location.href.split('/').pop())
```

Comment: I was thinking this too, but what if I have a URL like: example.com/http ://google.com/otherPage.js    how can I just split up the different parts?

Comment: or even example.com/index.php?page=http: //google.com

Answer (score 4):

You need to split the array and get the last portion. You can do it like this

```
var a = window.location.pathname.split("/");
console.log(a[a.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I were to just do `console.log(a[-1]);`, how come it says `undefined` in the console?

Comment: @Prateek: my solution is independent of the size of the URL. The objective was to achieve the last part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("/"+window.location.pathname.split("/")[2] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var path = "www.google.com/folder/folder/archive.php";
console.log(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select part from the last '/'.

```
var last =
```

window.location.toString().substr(window.location.toString().lastIndexOf('/'));

last will always be the path no matter which ever page you run this script.

eg: `http://www.example.com/../../../../../test.html`

The output will be test.html

```
http:// - Protocol
www - Server-Name (subdomain)
example - Second Level Domain (SLD)
com - Top Level Domain (TLD)
/test.html - Path
```