# How to delete a file image on amazon s3 when

Tags: node.js, express, multer-s3

I have a program Model, and i the program has an image attribute which I use multers3 to upload when creating the Program.

The challenge that I am facing now is that, when I delete the program, everything gets deleted on my local machine but I realized that the file(image) still exists on my Aws s3 console. How do I get the file deleted both on my database and on Amazon s3?

`Here are my Program routes`

This is how I delete my Program

```
router.delete("/:id/delete", function (req, res) {
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  let query = { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) };

   Program.deleteOne(query, function (err) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
    res.send("Success");
  });
});
```

and this is how i creates my program.

```
  router.post("/create", upload.single("cover"), async (req, res, next) => {
    const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null;
    const program = new Program({
      programtype: req.body.programtype,
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      programImage: req.file.location,
   });
 try {
   console.log(program);
   const programs = await program.save();
   res.redirect("/programs");
  } catch {
   if (program.programImage != null) {
    removeprogramImage(program.programImage);
  }
  res.render("programs/new");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through the Multer-s3 repo, I can't find anything which mentions deleting from s3. There is [this function](https://github.com/badunk/multer-s3/blob/168eb90c0f050760f791f1e97ced72253e01a6aa/index.js#L209) in the source code, but, I can't figure out how to use it.

You could try using the AWS SDK directly via `deleteObject`:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: 'access-key-id',
    secretAccessKey: 'access-key',
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
});

s3.deleteObject({ Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: 'image.jpg' }, (err, data) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem which is "that the file(image) still exists on my Aws s3 console" it could be because of passing image location instead of image name
When uploading the image to aws here is the respone

```
{
  fieldname: 'name',
  originalname: 'apple.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  size: 59654,
  bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
key: 'apple-1426277135446.png', //=> what i needed to pass as(key)
  acl: 'public-read',
contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
contentDisposition: null,
storageClass: 'STANDARD',
serverSideEncryption: null,
metadata: null,
location: 'https://my-bucket-name.Xx.xu-eXst-3.amazonaws.com/apple-
1426277135446.png', // => this is what i was passing to deleteObject as "key" 
etag: '"CXXFE*#&SHFLSKKSXX"',
versionId: undefined
 }
```

my problem was that i was passing the image location instead of the image name
in deleteObject function

```
s3.deleteObject({ Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: 'image.jpg' }, (err, data) 
 // key in the argument has to be the filename with extension without 

// URL like:  https://my-bucket-name.s3.ff-North-1.amazonaws.com/

  => {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

so eventually i could extract the name of the file(image) with extension
and passed to the function above
here is what i used the function from this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url)

```
function parseUrlFilename(url, defaultFilename = null) {
// 'https://my-bucket-name.Xx.xu-eXst-3.amazonaws.com/apple-
1426277135446.png'
let filename = new URL(url, 
"https://example.com").href.split("#").shift().split("?").shift().split("/").pop(); //No need to change "https://example.com"; it's only present to allow for processing relative URLs.
if(!filename) {
    if(defaultFilename) {
        filename = defaultFilename;
    //No default filename provided; use a pseudorandom string.
    } else {
        filename = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
    }
}
    // resulting apple-1426277135446.png'
    return filename;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and fixed by given code,

```
  s3.deleteObjects(
    {
      Bucket: 'uploads-images',
      Delete: {
        Objects: [{ Key: 'product-images/slider-image.jpg' }],
        Quiet: false,
      },
    },
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log('err ==>', err);
      console.log('delete successfully', data);
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    }
  );
```

This works exactly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Example of file deletion from url (file location) on amazone server
This code allows you to have the fileKey from the url
Before you need install urldecode

### npm i urldecode

```js
public async deleteFile(location: string) {
    let fileKey = decoder(location)
    const datas = fileKey.split('amazonaws.com/')
    fileKey = datas.pop();
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'Your Bucket',
      Key: fileKey,
    };
    await this.AWS_S3.deleteObject(params).promise();
  }
```